# extract substring with regex that contains a period

Tags: regex

I have a list of names here

```
apple.fruit
appleOrder2.fruit
orange.fruit
```

I want to extrat just the fruit name

expected

```
apple
apple
orange
```

I have the regex `(.*)((Order)|(\.fruit))`

that returns at position one,

```
apple
appleOrder2
orange
```

I think the `\.` is messing up with Alternation character because when i did a test using

```
(.*)((Order)|(ge))
```

the alternation works fine returning at position 1

```
empty
apple
oran
```

Perl is being used

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lazy quantifier:

```
(.*?)(Order|\.fruit)
```

In your regex, the `.*` first matches the entire string, then backtracks one character at a time until the alternation `Order|\.fruit` matches. Since that's the case after six backtracks already, the regex engine never gets to the point where it might find the other, earlier alternative. Solution: Tell the regex engine to match as few characters as possible by adding a `?` to the quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is just too greedy for your regex. Try:

```
(.+?)(?:Order2)?\.fruit
```

Comment: @Justin No, why? `.+` as in "one or more characters". Which is also not as greedy as `.*`.

Comment: @gore, See my question here.  I don't think you want to be using the term 'greedy.' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant-q

Comment: @goreSplatter: Both are just as greedy.

Comment: Thanks! could you explain what does (?:Order2)? do? you took out the alternation character too is that a typo or you meant that? I guess the ? is to tell regex engine to do a lazy search, but what is the : and the second ?

Comment: @freshWoWer `(?: ... )` means grouping, but not capturing. The question mark behind that means "one match or zero". So the whole grouping of "Order2" is matched either once or not at all. See [Justin's previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant-q) for details on that. @Justin [perlre](http://www.ryerson.ca/perl/manual/pod/perlre.html) uses "greedy". So do I.

Answer (score 0):

> (.*[!?^Order]|[!?^.fruit])((Order[0-9])|(.fruit)|((Order[0-9])|(.fruit)))

Answer (score 0):

In your original expression:

```
(.*)((Order)|(\.fruit))
```

the (Order) group is insufficient to match the "Order2" component of your second example string. I think something like e.g.:

```
(.*)((Order[0-9]?)|(\.fruit))
```

or similar would be able to also match the trailing integer (assuming it's not always "Order2").

Answer (score 0):

try ^([a-z]*)(\n)* [ asterix after(\n), and after[a-z] ], it takes any characters from each line. More detailed : "^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\n)*"