# In Regex, why is "((.|\s)*?)" different than "\s*.*"

Tags: regex

Not a complete newbie, but I still don't understand everything about Regular expressions. I was trying to use Regex to strip out <p> tags and my first attempt

```
<p\s*.*>
```

was so greedy it caught the whole line

```
<p someAttributes='example'>SomeText</p>
```

I got it to work with

```
((.|\s)*?)
```

This seems like it should be just as greedy, can anyone help me understand why it isnt?

Trying to make this question as language non-specific as possible, but I was doing this with ColdFusion's reReplaceNoCase if it makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a HTML parser for this?

Comment: I could explain why I'm using what I'm using but it doesn't really matter to answer the question at hand.

Comment: Well, I think it could be done in a fool-proof manor with a HTML parser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key difference is the `*?` part, which creates a **reluctant quantifier**, and so it tries to match as little as possible. The standard quantifier `*` is a **greedy quantifier** and tries to match as much as possible.

See e.g. [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

As Seth Robertson noted, you might want to use a regex that does not depend on the greedy/reluctant behaviour. Indeed, you can write a possessive regex for best performance:

```
<p\s*+[^>]*+>
```

Here, `\s*+` matches any number of white space, while `[^>]*+` matches any number of characters except `>`. Both quantifiers do not track back in case of a mismatch, which improves runtime in case of a mismatch, and for some regex implementations also in case of a match (because internal backtracking data can be omitted).

Note that, if there are other tags starting with `<p` (didn't write HTML directly for a long time), you match these too. If you don't want that, use a regex like this:

```
<p(\s++[^>]*+)?>
```

This makes the whole section between `<p` and `>` optional.

Comment: Thanks, helping me to understand a lot here. Little confused on what the '++' is doing I get that this will only match if p followed > or p [space]+anything but > followed by >, but it seems like the second + is redundant. What am I not getting there?

Comment: The second `+` is the quantifier modifier: It makes the quantifier `+` possessive: `\s+` is greedy (match most), `\s+?` is reluctant (match least), `\s++` is possessive (match most without backtracking).

Comment: I have some reading to do on backtracking I think. I have a very tenuous grasp on when it will and won't occur. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Consider this article (and the rest of the site): http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, either regex will match absolutely anything, so the question is moot.  Using non-greedy parser will probably come closer to what you want but still could have very unexpected results.

While you should not be matching html/xml with a RE, you probably want something like:

```
<p\s*([^>]*)>
```

Which would put any attributes of p into $1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p\s*.*>
```

Is looking for 'p', 0 or more spaces, 0 or more characters, '>' .
The group "any character" contains '>', so the regular expression find the whole line.