# What does a regex character class followed by a ?+ mean?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that contains a character class followed by TWO "cadinality" characters - not sure what else they are called.  If it matters the regex engine it's running on is the built in java regex.  The java string literal is:

```
"[a-zA-Z]{2}[ -]?+\\d{6}"
```

Or in non java land:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[ -]?+\d{6}
```

So specifically what does the `[ -]?+` part mean?  From testing as far as i can tell it's like the + isn't even there (originally I thought due to 'order of operations' that i wasn't aware of perhaps it would get applied to everything in front of it like there were parenthesis there).

The following pass:

```
ab123456, ab-123456, ab 123456
```

The following fail:

```
aa--123456, aa  123456, aa - -123456, aa-aa-123456
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), essentially meaning that the `?` will not give up its match for backtracking. It does not affect the number of repetitions that the `?` will match - it will still be zero or one (greedy). The `[ -]` preceding it is simply a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing the space and hyphen characters.

Other quantifier operators can also be made possessive by adding a `+` (i.e. `*+` or `++` would be possessive versions of `*` and `+`, respectively).

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly there wouldn't be much performance increase here because we're only matching against 1 character maximum anyway right?

Comment: @Russ: In this case I'd say you're correct, you don't gain much (if anything, really). That expression is already pretty restrictive.

Answer (score 4):

`?+` indicates a possessive quantifier. Have a look at this SO answer for more info [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

```
[a-zA-Z]    # Match a single character present in the list below
               # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
               # A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
   {2}         # Exactly 2 times
[ -]        # Match a single character present in the list below
               # The character “ ”
               # The character “-”
   ?+          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, 
               # without giving back (possessive)
\d          # Match a single digit 0..9
   {6}         # Exactly 6 times
```