# Proper way to prevent memory overflow, knowing the allowed memory size, but being unable to change it

Tags: php

After searching stackoverflow for an answer, I decided that the only problems that were treated was those regarding the extension of the maximum allowed memory. My question is if anyone knows how to insert a proper brake in case the scripts might fail due to the exhausting the memory.

This as for point A, also this in very close relation to another problem for which I failed to find an answer, meaning point B, and that is the time limit: another set of answers on how to extend the time limit using ini_set, and so on, possible solution were found by manually create break points in case the script already over-exceeded a proper time. And that was very fine, but having no control over a script you are loading might be impossible to prevent it.

Now, back to the question, does anyone know how to properly prevent such errors with a safe method? And if there really was an answered question regarding this subject, please link me to it.

Best regards,

Comment: "in case the scripts might fail due to the exhausting the memory" - you should have an idea of your memory requirements. Are you trying to fix the symptoms, rather than the cause?

Comment: Well, let's suppose that we want read some error_logs (very big error logs maybe) by unknown size, and we want to stop the execution before it fails, and save the state, and then to resume the reading of the file after we free some memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach to reducing the amount of memory that a program might use is to break the problem into smaller pieces, iteratively refine answers, use files on disk in place of memory for structures, etc. Without knowing details of your application, it's impossible to really suggest the *best* approach

But consider the task of sorting a 100 megabyte input file in perhaps 100kb of memory space; you might think the task impossible without actually holding all 100 megabytes in memory at once. However, you can easily split this problem into smaller pieces in many different approaches:

- perhaps sort all lines starting with integers [0-1000 into one file, 1001-2000 into another file, 2001-3000 into a third file, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) Once all the lines are segregated into different files, sort each file, and then merge the input files with a simple concatenation.
- perhaps sort the first 1000 lines at a time, store them into a temporary file, the next 1000 lines into another temporary file, and so on; then [merge the output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) by selecting the lowest output from each file, outputting it, removing it from its file, and iterating.

Consider the task of image editing: rather than loading an entire image into memory, you might read into memory only the portions you're going to work on, do the operation, and immediately re-write the contents back to disk.

Or, if your problem is a large regular expression match, you might have a significant [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) problem where too much state is being stored at once. You could convert to [different matching operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers/5319996#5319996) to prevent backtracking and perhaps solve the problem with multiple matches.

It depends on the problem you've got to solve how you can break it into smaller pieces to reduce overall memory use. Note that many of these techniques can *increase* execution time, because they require more disk IO or re-solving problems that could have been kept in memory. Sometimes they speed up execution time because the less data you work with or keep, the better [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), and the better the caching can work. (This is rare. See [Programming Pearls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Pearls) for a very striking case of speed up due to simpler problem solving...)

Comment: For images is harder to read them individually, as it seems that native functions requires for editing to create some kind of raw data from it, can you please tell me how would you do this in case of an image. For files it might be simpler, consider the tokenizer, you could parse it line by line, and to end with, is it possible any preventing measure to be taken in case of including files against memory fail? I am aware that good coding practices and good architecture leads to no problems but sometimes you need to force the line in order to treat all possible cases of this kind of errors.

Comment: It depends upon why the file would need to be included; if it is the _only_ file being included and sent directly to the client, the `sendfile(2)` system call is wonderful -- it tasks the _kernel_ with sending the data. If it is for use in the PHP interpreter, there's not much you can do -- you've got to rely on the PHP interpreter, afterall.