# PHP: Regular Expression for <ul> lists

Tags: php, regex

I need a PHP regular expression pattern to select separately all lists `<ul></ul>` from string.
The string is like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
....
```

I need to extract both lists and save them in array, so the result would look like:

```
$listsarray[0] = first list code from <ul> to </ul>.
$listsarray[1] = second list code, etc..
```

What I have tried, but this doesn't work as expected. If there is more than two lists, it selects first two as one (I don't know why, I'm a novice at regular expressions):

```
$content = 'the content like above...';
$pattern = '/<ul[^.]*<\/ul>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $listsarray)
```

Comment: DO NOT parse HTML with regexp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, it's a bad idea as HTML is not a regular language... You can use other methods such as [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [the built in DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parse it easily without regular expressions

If you insist, what you're looking for is reluctant matching (instead of greedy)

change `*` to `*?`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers) about the difference and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) on why it's a bad idea to try and parse html with regular expressions

Comment: A better solution for parsing HTML is Tidy. It parses even broken HTML, lets you manipulate the tree structure and can output perfectly valid (X)HTML.

Comment: Great idea, I'll edit the answer to include better alternatives to regular expressions

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you very much *? solved all my problems.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hello, I guess you was right that parsing HTML with regular expression is bad idea, something is not working as expected, so I would like to ask: can you give some example how to do the same (similar) task with Tidy or DOMDocument, I have no experience with these and couldn't find some script example online. Can you help please?

Comment: if you check the documentation at php.net there are plenty of examples there regarding usage

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<ul>(?<ulContent>.*?)</ul>
```

and get group named *ulContent*