# PHP: Extract specifig tags from HTML code string

Tags: php, html-parsing

I will start by mentioning my first question about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359502/php-regular-expression-for-ul-lists)

What I need is to get all `<ul>` lists in array from a HTML string so I could manipulate with them by splitting each list in half (creating two lists out of one) to show each list in two columns by floating them. Examples:

Source:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor et amet...<br />
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
Lorem ipsum dolor et amet...<br />
NEXT UL LIST GOES HERE... etc..
```

Needed result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor et amet...<br />
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>    
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
NEXT UL LIST GOES HERE... etc..
```

I know about CSS floating `<li>` but this would give list in wrong order like:

```
Lorem ipsum...
list item 1     list item 2
list item 3     list item 4
list item 5     list item 6
```

What is not needed. So I decided that the solution could be splitting each list in half (creating two lists out of one) and then floating them.

As you can see in my previous question my first idea was to do it by using `preg_match_all()` PHP function. But it doesn't work very good. And as users suggested that using regular expressions to parse HTML is a bad idea so:

Can someone please explain how to do this by using DOMDocument or any other method? How to extract lists from html content so I could manipulate with them as needed?

Comment: Are you generating the original page with PHP, and if so, would it be a viable option to split the list before generating the html?

Comment: @Andrew no the whole page is not generated with PHP. Its a basic HTML/PHP file that connects to database to get current page content. The page is like:
`<html><head>...<body>`
`<?php include('databasecconnection.php');`
`mysql_query(... //to get a content`
`echo $content; ?>...` and lists is in `$content`