# Parsing Addresses with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want my regular expression to be able to recognize a street address that ends in a zip code and starts with a number.

So if my sample string is

```
'abcd 123 abcd 1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345 hello, world'
```

I want it to match only

```
1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345
```

I'm stuck on using

```
.match(/\d+.*\d{5}/)
```

but this returns

```
123 abcd 1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345
```

How can I get it to return the closest instance of numbers?

Comment: Regex is not intelligent enough to guess what your address is. It will give you the string that matches your pattern.

Comment: I might try this: http://smartystreets.com/how-to/regex-street-address. I'm guessing you're not going to be able to get all the way there with regex. Address parsing has a lot of complexities that don't immediately meet the eye.

Comment: Well I guess all I'm wondering is if there is a way for it to match the last instance of \d+ rather than the first

Answer (score 0):

This is also an option for you:

```
.match(/\d+(\s(\D+|\d+\D{2})){3,6}\d{5}/)
```

This means:

1. Look for a group of digits
2. Make sure it's followed by between 3 and 6 groups of: (one space + some characters). Those characters can either be non-digits, or combinations of numbers and two letters. The latter type of group, `\d+\D{2}`, will address bits such as **1st** and **3rd**, etc. in your address as The Tin Man mentions. But it won't match **Apt. 2** correctly.
3. Giving your groups a number range between 3 and 6, and you can adjust those numbers of course, will make it so that your regex will match addresses that are a little different.
4. Make sure there is a zip code at the end of the match

P.S. [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
.match(/\d+(\D)*?\d{5}/)
```

I bet above might be what you want. Basically, if you don't want extra digits in between you can use `(\D)` instead of `(.)`. The additional `?` tells the regex interpreter to do reluctant match rather than greedy match. In other words, the interpreter would return the shortest match.

A good question for [greedy vs. reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your pattern is that regex are greedy by default. `.*` is grabbing too much and needs to be told to be more selective. Also, `.` will grab any type of character, which is probably not what you want.

I'd start with `/(\d+\D+?\d{5})/` which captures:

```
1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345
```

For example:

```
'a 123 a 1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345 foo'[/(\d+\D+?\d{5})/, 1]
=> "1600 Penn Ave. Washington D.C. 12345"
```

The pattern means:

1. Start with a minimum of one digit...
2. Followed by at least one non-digit, selecting the minimal amount to reach to...
3. A five-digit number.

All answers would probably fail if you get an address that has a numerically named street, like `1st`.