# JavaScript Regular Expression - strange results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sample string below:

```
var nodeTest = "<node1>xxxxxxx<x> xxx</node1>xxx xx</x>x x x xxxxxx <node2>xx x x xxxxxxxxxx</node2> xxxxx";
```

I am trying to match all nodes with and without white spaces so anything (numbers, white space, text and all characters - think everything!) between <> including <>. I have tried many configurations but they don't seem to work intuitively, my most recent bit of logic being this:

```
var nodePairs = nodeTest.match(/<(.*)>/gi);
```

But it matches the ENTIRE test string. Can anyone offer any clues as to where I might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what your main intentions are but in case you have difficulty with really complex xmls/htmls then I would recommend that you use jquery to parse them example -

 $("<node1>xxxxxxx<x> xxx</node1>xxx xx</x>x x x xxxxxx <node2>xx x x xxxxxxxxxx</node2> xxxxx")

Comment: I will give jquery a go later thanks -my objective was to pick all nodes out of a large body of text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy - meaning it'll match *as much as possible* (in this case, from the first `<` to the last `>`).

If you want lazy search, use `.*?` to match *as little as possible*.

Comment: this cured it thanks! Another lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` means that the `.` is greedy, it'll match as much as it can, and that explains your results.

What you probably want to get, is this regex:

```
<node(\d)>(.*?)<\/node\1>
```

The result you want is in the second captured group. See how it works [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/yE9lH6).

The `\1` by the way refers to the first captured group.

If you have nodes with higher numbers than `node0` to `node9`, then you'd prefer:

```
<node(\d+)>(.*?)<\/node\1>
```

Comment: May I suggest `\d+`? :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sure, I'll add that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the code example! I don't see how `\d+` would work as isn't that digits only?

Comment: @user1360809 Don't you have "node" and a number attached to it? Also, simply changing the greedy `.*` to `.*?` won't get you the desired results since you have `>` characters inside the nodes.

Comment: `node\d` means "*the string node followed by a single digit*" whereas `node\d+` means "*the string node followed by a digit repeated 1 or more times*" (essentially any number except for numbers with decimals)

Comment: ah, good point! the node and number is only a test, but is it not (not) correct html/xml to have nested <> inside <>, you would have to use a different representation, no?

Comment: Ahh, since it's for html/xml. Yea, you'd have the `<>` symbols as `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use a binding character class to avoid the greedy/lazy problem:

```
/<([^>]+)>/
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this but it was more like `/<[^]>/`