# What exactly does .*? do in regex? ".*?([a-m/]*).*"

Tags: java, regex

For `".*?([a-m/]*).*"` matching the string `"fall/2005"`, I thought the `".*"` will match any character 0 or more times. However, since there is a `?` following `.*`, it only matches for 0 or 1 repetitions. So I thought `.*?` will match `'f'` but I'm wrong.

What is wrong in my logic?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `?` here acts as a 'modifier' if I can call it like that and makes `.*` match the least possible match (termed 'lazy') until the next match in the pattern.

In `fall/2005`, the first `.*?` will match up to the first match in `([a-m/]*)`, which is just before `f`. Hence, `.*?` matches 0 characters so that `([a-m/]*)` will match `fall/` and since `([a-m/]*)` cannot match anymore, the next part of the pattern `.*` matches what's left in the string, meaning `2005`.

In contrast to `.*([a-m/]*).*`, you would have `.*` match as much as possible first (meaning the whole string) and try to go back to make the other terms match. Except that the problem is with the other quantifiers being able to match 0 characters as well, so that `.*` alone will match the whole string (termed 'greedy').

---

Maybe a different example will help.

```
.*ab
```

In:

```
aaababaaabab
```

Here, `.*` will match as much characters as possible and then  try to match `ab`. Thus, `.*` will match `aaababaaab` and the remainder will be matched by `ab`.

```
.*?ab
```

In:

```
aaababaaabab
```

Here, `.*?` will match as little as possible until it can match `ab` in that regex. The first occurrence of `ab` is here:

```
aaababaaabab
  ^^
```

And so, `.*?` matches `aa` while `ab` will match `ab`.

Comment: Finally, someone who fully explains this correctly.  The other answers make it sound like `.*?` always matches only the empty string.  Mind showing a counter-example to demonstrate when `.*?` would actually match something, maybe even when it's helpful (i.e. `z01234z56789z`, trying to get only what is between the first two `z`s)?

Comment: @NickC I was crafting one :)

Comment: @Jerry do you live on here? ;)

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for the detailed explanation and the example. For .*?ab, doesnt it fail to complete the match of the whole string of aaababaaabab since there is nothing to complete the remaining match of (abaaabab) after the first aaab?

Comment: `.*?` would match the first `aa` unless you used the `g` modifier.

Comment: @IannWu It depends on the function you're using in Java. For instance, `.matches` will try to match the whole string, while `.matcher` will try to find any match in the string. Most functions with regex apply a pattern onto any match v/s the whole string, and what's the basis of regex searches :)

Comment: @hwnd There's no g modifier in Java.

Comment: Ahh I meant in general, but yes `matches` in Java, sorry I am used to PCRE =)

Comment: @IannWu I'm glad it helped you! ^^

Comment: @hwnd Yup, that's another reason why the language is important in regex, because of those different flavours! And Java's one of the flavours I don't particularly like ^^; But oh well, gotta do what we can with it.

Comment: @hwnd Also, no, I don't live on here. I just happened to be around xD

Answer (score 3):

In regex:

> **?** : Occurs no or one times, ? is short for {0,1}

***?**  : ? after a quantifier makes it a reluctant quantifier, it tries to find the smallest match.

Comment: Do you mean ? will always find the smallest match, which is nothing?

Comment: @IannWu No {0,1}} is for 0 or 1 occurence and not for numbers

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you have a string input like this

```
this is stackoverflow
```

and you use regex

```
.*
```

so output will be

```
this is stackoverflow
```

but if you use regex

```
.*?
```

your out put will be

```
this
```

So from the above example it is clear that if you use .* it will give you whole string.
to prevent this if you want only first cherector before space you should use **.*?**

For more practical knowledge you can check http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Actually `.*?` by itself would choose to match `0` characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` (question mark) is considered *lazy* here or so called *not greedy*.

- Read [Greedy vs. reluctant vs. possessive quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

Your regular expression:

```
.*?         any character except newline \n (0 or more times)
            (matching the least amount possible)

 (          group and capture to \1:

 [a-m/]*    any character of: 'a' to 'm', '/' (0 or more times)
            (matching the most amount possible)

 )          end of \1

 .*         any character except newline \n (0 or more times)
            (matching the most amount possible)
```