# RegEx to pull everything between script tags

Tags: c#, regex

Is there some kind of RegEx pattern I can use to pull everything in between two script tags (including the script tags themselves) in an HTML file? For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- A bunch of HTML here -->
        <script>
            // A bunch of javascript here
        </script>
        <script type="type/javascript">
            // Another block of javascript here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to be able to do it capture everything between the `<script>` tags. I'd like each block of javascript to be a new match. Is this possible with RegEx? I'm using C# as my language. If RegEx cannot do this, I'd like ideas for some kind of parser library that could do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @L.B - That question has nothing to do with mine. He's trying to parse HTML/XHTML. I'm not trying to parse anything. I just want to extract the javascript from a file.

Comment: Which one is correct?  a) you don't understand what you read b) You don't know what you are doing

Comment: @L.B - Quote from the link you provided: "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.". Again, I'm not trying to parse anything. I just want to extract javascript. And when I say "extract javascript", I'm not wanting to parse javascript. I just want to cut it. Like a word processor.

Comment: It is called *parsing* (you want to parse the html and extract info out of it)

Comment: @L.B - From Wikipedia: "[Parsing] is the process of analysing a string of symbols". I dont want to analyze anything. I just want to cut it. Like <ctrl>+X. I'm not trying to make a program that can analyze the javascript and do anything with it. I just want to cut it out of the HTML. That's it

Comment: You want to analyze the  string(html) and get the info from it matching `script` tags

Comment: @L.B - I don't want to "analyze" the html. What I want is to "search" for "<script>" in the html file, cut everything from the "<script>" to the next "</script">. Thats it. string.IndexOf can do this very easily. I'm trying to use regex though instead of indexof.

Comment: What is so hard to understand: (excluding simple cases) you can not use regex(and string ops like *string.IndexOf*) to parse (extract some info from)  html. I guess you will get some answers that can work for some simple cases. but you have to use an html parser instead. (BTW: *which libray to use* is an off-topic as I voted for close)

Comment: Methinks that finding the _correct_ end tag is a complex issue. What if the same series of characters occurs inside a Javascript string literal? Only by parsing the complete language can you be sure that you are matching semantic elements correctly.

Comment: @HABO -- I am writing all the javascript myself and I can all but guarantee that I will not have a javascript string literal that contains a closing script tag. I'm writing this to remove all the javascript from my own html files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can all but guarantee that I will not have a javascript string literal that contains a closing script tag

If this is the case... you can try with the following regex:

```
<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>
```

The group within the  tags is [not greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319978/1792585) so the regex will match the first  it finds.

But I **strongly** recommend to use an HTML parser.