# Java Pattern Matching with Groups

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group

When I run this code, it prints out only the groups found in the first pattern it matched per line. However, there are multiple strings I want to replace in each line and I want it to print out the specific groups for each string in the pattern it matched. How can I change it so that it prints out the groups specific to the patterns/strings it found in each line instead of printing only the groups in the first pattern match it found?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

public class RealReadFile {
    private static final String fileName = "KLSadd.tex";

    private Scanner myFile = null;

    // No-args constructor, create a new scanner for the specific file defined
    // above

    public RealReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (myFile == null)
            myFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    }

    // One-arg constructor - the name of the file to open

    public RealReadFile(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (myFile != null)

            myFile.close();

        myFile = new Scanner(new File(name));

    }
    public boolean endOfFile() {    // Return true is there is no more input

        return !myFile.hasNext();   // hasNext() returns true if there is more input, so I negate it

    }

    public String nextLine() {
        return myFile.nextLine().trim();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        RealReadFile file = new RealReadFile();
        while(!file.endOfFile()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_\\{?([^\\}]+)\\}?)");
            Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
            while (pochhammer.find()){
                System.out.println(line);
                String line2=pochhammer.replaceAll("\\\\pochhammer{" + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
                System.out.println(line2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `Matcher`'s `find()` and `replaceAll()` functions. It makes no sense to use `replaceAll()` inside a `find()` loop:

```
while (pochhammer.find()){
   System.out.println(line);
   String line2=pochhammer.replaceAll("\\\\pochhammer{" + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
   System.out.println(line2);
}
```

To replace all instances, you'll need to change it to something like this:

```
StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();
while(pochhammer.find())  {
   pochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{" + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
}
pochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
System.out.println(rplcmntBfr);
```

Accessing individual match-groups ***and*** using `replaceAll(s)`

```
pochhammer.replaceAll("\\\\pochhammer{" + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
```

makes no sense, because `group(i)` is only for use with `find()`, yet `replaceAll(s)` is for replacing *all matches in the line at once*.

Here's a tutorial on making replacements with `find()`, `appendReplacement(sb,s)` and `appendTail(sb)`: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#appendreplacement-appendtail-methods

You may also want to take a look at this question, regarding the difference between *[Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)*, as I suspect that the quantifiers in your regex may need to change from `+`, to either `+?` or `++`. But since I don't know what your input or expected output looks like, I can only guess at this part.

The problem I mention above is the big one.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't that mean it won't attempt to match the rest of the line? I need to match and replace the rest of the line too.

Comment: I realized something major that I didn't address before. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your regular expression is secondary to the `replaceAll` versus `find()` problem. I've eliminated the regular expression part from my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem with the specific groups :).