# Regex to capture characters including whitespace between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse shortcodes:

```
[shortcode]the content inside[/shortcode]
```

This works fine, as it is all one line, but as soon as i have multiple lines, I'm having trouble capturing that group:

```
[shortcode]
this is 

the content
[/shortcode]
```

My current expression for matching inline text is: `\[([^\]]*?)\](.*)\[\/\1\]`

I'm having trouble modifying the `(.*)` section to capture everything including new lines.
This is to be used in javascript, so I can't use the `/s` modifier.

An example can be seen here: http://regex101.com/r/nZ1hZ4

Comment: [\w\W] is nifty in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Javasctipt doesn't suport DOTALL flag you can use `[\s\S]` instead of `DOT` to make it match new lines:

```
\[([^\]]*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! For my own sake, can you tell me in human terms what `[\s\S]*?` translates to? I know `\s` is any whitespace char, and `\S` is any non whitespace char, but what about `*?`?

Comment: Actually @anubhava I just read through the explained section at the bottom, makes sense. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @Atticus You should read [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture everything, use `[^]` instead of `.`

```
\[([^\]]*?)\]([^]*)\[\/\1\]
```

Comment: `[^]` fails and says it's an incomplete character class. If i do something like `[^SOME SYMBOL]` it will work. But is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: @Atticus, can you give me an expression that doesn't work for you? It works for me.

Comment: @anubhava negation takes precedence over literal interpretation... or I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: If `[^]` works in JS great, a lot of other engines might see it as an unbalanced `[` because the caret, in that position represents a construct. Same would happen with `[]`, a class without content.

Comment: @sln that was the issue -- treated it as unbalanced without a following rule after the character. Wasn't sure what to fill it with.

Comment: @Atticus Which browser? What expression where you using?