# Regex to match number specific number in a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fix a regex I create.

I have an url like this:

http://www.demo.it/prodotti/822/Panasonic-TXP46G20E.html

and I have to match the product ID (822).

I write this regex

```
(?<=prodotti\/).*(?<=\/)
```

and the result is "822/"

My match is always a group of numbers between two / /

Comment: `(?<=prodotti\/)\d+`?

Comment: Use a lookahead instead of a lookbehind, also use a reluctant quantifier instead of a greedy one `(?<=prodotti\/).*?(?=\/)`. [See the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there!

Simply use:

```
(?<=prodotti\/).*?(?=\/)
```

instead of:

```
(?<=prodotti\/).*(?<=\/)
```

And you're good ;)

See it working [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kR1cM9).

---

I've actually just changed two things:

1. replaced that **lookbehind** of yours (`(?<=\/)`) by its matching **lookahead**... so it asserts that we can match a `/` AFTER the last character consumed by `.*`.
2. changed the `greediness` of your matching pattern, by using `.*?` instead of `.*`. Without that change, in case of an url that has several `/` following `prodotti/`, you wouldn't have stopped to the first one.
   i.e., given the input string: `http://www.demo.it/prodotti/822/Panasonic/TXP46G20E.html`, it would have matched `822/Panasonic`.

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation... ? :)

Comment: now is ok. I'm learning regex so I want also to know what's my fault :)

Comment: Hey, you're right to ask, and actually my answer had no explanation before I edited it (within a very short time), so that was totally legitimate ;)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer it your problem is solved :)