# Pattern matcher using Greedy and Reluctant

Tags: java, regex

In java `regex` I have read about [Greedy and Reluctant Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers). They mentioned as

> A reluctant or "non-greedy" quantifier first matches as little as
>   possible. So the .* matches nothing at first, leaving the entire
>   string unmatched

In this example

> source: `yyxxxyxx`
>   pattern: `.*xx`

greedy quantifier `*` and produces

```
0 yyxxxyxx
```

reluctant qualifier `*?`, and we get the following:

```
0 yyxx
4 xyxx
```

Why result of `yxx`, `yxx` not possible even it is the smallest possible value?

Answer (score 2):

The regex engine returns the first and leftmost match it find as a result.

Basically it tries to match the pattern starting from the first character. If it doesn't find a corresponding match, the transmission jumps in and it tries again from the second character, and so on.

If you use `a+?b` on `bab` it will first try from the first `b`. That doesn't work, so we try from the second character.

But here it finds a match right from the first character. Starting from the second isn't even considered, we found a match so we return.

If you apply `a+?b` on `aab`, we try at the first `a` and find an overall match: end of story, no reason to try anything else.

**To sum up**: the regex engine goes from the left to the right, so laziness can only affect the right side length.