# Regex not returning expected result for text betwen slashes

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to recognize and parse the following string:

```
HTTPS Access https://ftp.abc.def.com/dir1<about:blank%20https:/ftp.abc.def.com/dir1>
```

What I want to pull out is

```
host = ftp.abc.def.com
```

I use the following regular expression:

```
(?i)https:\/\/<?host>\S+)\/(?<dir>\S+)
```

which gives me

```
host = ftp.abc.def.com/dir1<about:blank%20https:/ftp.abc.def.com
```

Why is the host being matched all the way to the last / and not just the first?

Comment: [Greediness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers#5319978).

Comment: add `?` to `<?host>\S+`, so it would be `<?host>\S+?`

Comment: I would use the right tool for the job: `string host = new Uri(input.Substring(input.IndexOf("https://")), UriKind.Absolute).Host`. The result is: `"ftp.abc.def.com"`