# Simplify & Fix Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to working with regular expressions and was wondering if the following regex could somehow be simplified...

```
{{(?:[\s]+)?(.*)([\s]+)?}}
```

I am trying to get the string out of the following pattern...

```
{{SOME_STRING}}
{{    SOME_STRING}}
{{  SOME_STRING   }}
{{  SOME-STRING      }}
{{  SomE STRING  }}
```

Additionally, it doesn't quite work right as there should not be any trailing spaces on the match.

Regex101 Link: http://regex101.com/r/kT9yT5

Comment: Write `\s*` instead of `(?:[\s]+)?` for one.

Answer (score 1):

> there should not be any trailing spaces on the match

You can try below regex and get the matched group

```
/{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}/g
```

that means every thing that is enclosed inside `{{` and `}}` are grouped using *Reluctant quantifiers*.

Here is [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fR6qH4)

Read more about [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

Comment: @Braj you need to escape the curly braces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

**For A Direct Match, use `\K` Magic**

```
{{\s*\K[^}]+?(?=\s*}})
```

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/aW4kV4)

**Explanation**

- `{{\s*` matches the opening braces and any whitespace characters
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- The negated character class `[^}]+?` lazily matches any characters up to...
- The point where the lookahead `(?=\s*}})` can assert that what follows is spaces and the closing braces.

**Sample Code**

See the output at the bottom of the [live php demo](http://ideone.com/jnraqk).

```
$regex = '~{{\s*\K[^}]+?(?=\s*}})~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output**

```
[0] => SOME_STRING
[1] => SOME_STRING
[2] => SOME_STRING
[3] => SOME-STRING
[4] => SomE STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to remove all the trailing and beginning white spaces present inside the `{}`,

```
\{\{\s*(\w+[-\s]?\w+)\s*\}\}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hO4gO6)

**Explanation:**

- `\{\{` Literal opening curly braces `{{`
- `\s*` zero or more spaces.
- `\w+` One or more word characters.
- `[-\s]?` Optional `-` or space character.
- `\w+` One or more word characters.
- `\s*` Zero or more space characters.
- `\}\}` Literal closing curly braces `}}`

You code would be,

```
$regex = '~\{\{\s*(\w+[-\s]?\w+)\s*\}\}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZvsqCp)