# matching in between a long sentence with keywords

Tags: regex

target sentence:

```
$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system;$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system\host;$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\components\fds\ab_cdef_1.0\host;    $(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\somethingelse;
```

how should I construct my regex to extract item contains "..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system"

basically, I want to extract all those folders and may be more, they are all under \ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system:

```
$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system\host\abc;
$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system\host\123\123\123\123; 
$(SolDir)..\..\ABC\ccc\1234\ccc_am_system\host;
```

my current regex doesn't work and I can't figure out why

```
\$.*ccc\\1234\.*;
```

Comment: why you gave the start and end patterns in reverse order? What's the input and the expected output?

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that `*` is a greedy operator. It's greedily matching more than you intend it to. In many regex dialects, `*?` is the reluctant operator. I would first try using it like this:

```
\$.*?ccc\\1234.*?;
```

You can read up a bit more on greedy vs reluctant operators [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers).

If that doesn't work, you can try to be more specific with the characters you match than `.`. For example, you can match every non-semicolon character with an expression like this: `[^;]*`. You could use that idea this way:

```
\$[^;]*ccc\\1234[^;]*;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would store the captured strings inside group 1.

```
(\$.*?ccc\\1234\\.*?;)
```

You need to make the `*` quantifier to does a shortest match by adding `?` next to `*` . And also this `\.*` matches a literal dot zero or more times. It's wrong.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/10)

Comment: the problem with the above sample is that it matches $something;$..ccc\\1234;

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the best:

```
\$(.[^\$;])*ccc\\1234(.[^\$;])*;
```

it doesn't allow any over match whatsoever, if I use ?, it still matches more $ or ; more than once for some reason, but with above expression, that will never be case. Still thanks to all those who took the time to answer my question,.