# In a regex, what changes when you add a question mark to .+

Tags: php, regex

I was browsing old php sources and I found a pattern I don't understand (probably a copy/past from the internet some times ago ...).

Here is a simple exemple using it with php :

```
echo preg_replace('#color="(.+)"#', '$1', 'color="red" color="black"');
// Echo 'red" color="black', which is fine because the (.+) try to match the largest possible string.

echo preg_replace('#color="(.+?)"#', '$1', 'color="red" color="black"');
// Echo 'red black', why ? There is some black magic behind '(.+?)' I don't understand !
```

So what does the '?' do in '(.+?)' ?
I assume it says something like 'don't match the rest of the regex' but I'm looking for a detailed explanation !

Comment: `?` after `+` forces the regex  engine to do a shortest possible match (non-greedy or reluctant).

Comment: It is a reluctant quantifier. It looks for the smallest sequence that match the `.+`. More info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thanks, that was the information I was missing. It's very clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator; consuming as much as possible. Therefore, `.+` will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. Once you specify the question mark `+?`, you're telling the regex engine (**don't be greedy..** as soon as you find a double quote `"`... stop, you're done.)

Answer (score 1):

The `?` makes the match **non-greedy**, meaning that the expression `.+?` will match as few characters as possible to make the regex match, rather than matching as any as possible, which is the default behaviour.