# Java regular expression(grouping)

Tags: java, regex

I am try to write a regex to match conditional expressions, for example:

```
a!=2     1+2<4       f>=2+a
```

and I try to extract the operator.
My current regex is ".+([!=<>]+).+"

But the problem is that the matcher is always trying to match the shortest string possible in the group.

For example, if the expression is a!=2, then group(1) is "=", not "!=" which is what I expect.

So how should I modify this regex to achieve my goal?

Comment: `[!=<>]` can represent only one character. Read about [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) (especially about greedy and reluctant).

Comment: Reply to pshemo: sorry it was my typo when typing the question. Now it is corrected

Comment: Problem stays the same. First `.+` is greedy so it consumes characters which could be matched by `[!=<>]+`. You need to make it reluctant (or instead of `.` you can use negated character set to prevent matching `!=<>`).

Comment: BTW, instead of `Reply to pshemo` use `@pshemo` :) this way I will be notified about your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match an operator surrounded by something that is *not* an operator.

An operator, in your definition : [!=<>]

Inversely, not an operator would be : [^!=<>]

Then try :

```
[^!=<>]+([!=<>]+)[^!=<>]+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the reluctant or non-greedy versions (see [that other posr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319978/3545273) for extensive explain). In your example, it would be :

```
.+?([!=<>]+).+
```

But this regex could match incorrect comparisons like `a <!> b`, or `a =!><=! b` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.+(!=|[=<>]+).+
```

your regex is matching a single `!` because it is in `[]`

Everything put in brackets will match a single char, which means `[!=<>]` can match: `!, =, <, >`

Comment: Thank you, but this actually doesn't work. .+ still eats up !

Comment: No, it's the greediness of the leading `.+` that's causing the problem, as explained in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26474663/20938).