# Shortest match in regex from end

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Given an input string `fooxxxxxxfooxxxboo` I am trying to write a regex that matches `fooxxxboo` i.e. starting from the second foo till the last boo.

I tried the following

`foo.*?boo` matches the complete string `fooxxxxxxfooxxxboo`

`foo.*boo` also matches the complete string `fooxxxxxxfooxxxboo`

I read this [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers/5319978#5319978) and I understand their difference, but I am trying to match the shortest string from the end which matches the regex i.e. something like the regex to be evaluated from back.
Is there any way I can match only the last portion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
foo(?:(?!foo).)*?boo
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/8)

`(?:(?!foo).)*?` - Non-greedy match of any character but not of `foo` zero or more times. That is, before matching each character, it would check that the character is not the letter `f` followed by two `o`'s. If yes, then only the corresponding character will be matched.

**Why the regex `foo.*?boo` matches the complete string `fooxxxxxxfooxxxboo`?**

Because the first `foo` in your regex matches both the `foo` strings and the following `.*?` will do a non-greedy match upto the string `boo`, so we got two matches `fooxxxxxxfooxxxboo` and `fooxxxboo`. Because the second match present within the first match, regex engine displays only the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
.*(foo.*?boo)
```

Try this. Grab the capture i.e `$1` or `\1`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/9

Comment: Good to understand and more efficient it looks.