# R regex help: Perl s modifier + lookahead too aggressive

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I'm trying to remove all characters (including newlines) between two given substrings, using R's `gsub("regexp", "", string, perl=T)` (i.e. replace all matches with the empty string).

What I have so far is the regular expression `(?<=A)(?s:.)+(?=B)` where I use the `s` modifier to make the `.` match newline also. The problem is that when there are multiple occurences of the lookahead `B`, I only want to remove whatever lies between A and the first B:

I have `A remove \r\n this B but leave this B`

I want `AB but leave this B`

but so far what I get is `AB`

How can I modify the regex to make the lookahead stop at the first occurence?

Comment: In Perl, `A\KB(?=C)` is faster than `(?<=A)B(?=C)`. It's probably the same for PCRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it non greedy try this:

```
(?<=A)(?s:.)+?(?=B)
```

Comment: perfec, thanks! Sorry for the dumb question (in hindsight), I had done a lot of googling but didn't know the "greedy" term so never found the answer.

Comment: study here and be wise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers

Comment: The optional quantifier `*` is useless, should be non-optional.

Comment: Using the non-greedy modifier as anything but an optimization is fragile. I *think* you're safe if you only use one in the pattern, but that's it. Since it's easier and far clearer to avoid this dangerous construct in this case, I disagree with this solution.

Comment: In that context, it is better written as `(?s:.*?)` or `(?s:.+?)`. No need to rescope a single character.

Comment: @sln, I disagree. There's no difference between `(?s:.+?)` and `(?s:.)+?` in Perl (as seen using `perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/(?s:.)+?/'` and `perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/(?s:.+?)/'`), and there probably isn't any in PCRE.

Comment: @ikegami - Perl optimizes everything, never said there was a difference. Like you say `(?s:.)+?` is the same as `(?s:(?:(?:(?:.))))+?` same program steps. In other engines ? eh, not so sure this doesn't result in unneeded steps.

Comment: @ikegami - I don't think that `(?:(?:(?:` to `)))`  is technically considered nesting and is a single group. Whereas a group that is quantified is not technically the same as a group of quantified items, even though it could be optimized out as in such a simple case as this. I would imagine some engines not doing that optimization.

Comment: @sln, What are you talking about? How is that remotely relevant?

Comment: @ikegami  - I'm talking about optimization's. I guess I'm saying `(?s:.+?)` is in no way even closely or remotely the same as `(?s:.)+?`..

Comment: @sln, I've already proved they are exactly the same, so I really don't care that you think they're completely different.

Comment: @sln, I just noticed you said I said  "`(?s:.)+?` is the same as `(?s:(?:(?:(?:.))))+?`". I never said anything of the kind. I have no idea if it's true or not (nor do I care).

Comment: `(?s:(?:(?:(?:.))))+?` optimizes to same code as `(?s:.)+?` ,  `use re 'debug';`

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific case where using `Dot-All`, the dot, and quantifiers should
not be used. The read on it is confusing and doesn't convey its real intent.

`(?<=A)[^B]+(?=B)`

Comment: This would indeed work perfectly in the sample case I gave. What if I wanted instead to lookahead to `\\\\centering` ? (I'm using this regex to clean up some legacy LaTeX files)

Comment: @user28400 - Using `.*` or `.*?` is frought with danger, there are ways to not use it affectively, but just as a filler is dangerous. As an example, in compound sub-expressions this `.*?` can be construed as greedy and _could_ not do what you think.

Comment: `(?:(?!STRING).)` is to `(?:STRING)` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`. (`s` modifier presumed)