# PHP pattern search and replace

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace

I have a bunch of rawr contents in database.

some containing string `http://www.example.com/subfolder/name.pdf` or `/subfolder/name.pdf`

I need a pattern replace on these to turn them into `/wp-content/uploads/old/subfolder/name.pdf` there can be many levels of subfolders!
`/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/file.pdf`

The pattern for finding I use is

```
/http[^\s]+pdf/
/href="\/[^\s]+pdf/
```

But how to replace the pattern with another pattern? ( the example above ^ )

I have

```
search for /http:\/\/www.example.com(.*).pdf"/
replace with /wp-content/uploads/old$1.pdf"

search for /href="\/pdf(.*)\.pdf">/
```

this works fine until there are more than 1 pdf links in one table cell

example

`<a href="/pdf/subdir/name.pdf">clickhere</a><a href="/pdf/subdir/name.pdf">2nd PDF</a>`

Comment: What have you tried? What are the conditions for the match? Are there any exceptions? Please include examples for both

Comment: Are you aware your regex matches "`xxxhttpxxxpdfxxxx.html`"?

Comment: Which database do you use? Regex replacement functions are available in oracle and by [some user defined functions](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) in mysql. A `preg_replace` code for this would be `$out = preg_replace('&^(http://www.example.com/)(.*[.]pdf)$&', '$1wp-content/uploads/$2', $in);` and the other likewise (if the URL is fixed; replace it by a pattern like `[^/]+` if not)

Comment: updated with what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this works fine until there are more than 1 pdf links in one table cell

The regex engine is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by default, and it consumes as much as it can attempting a match. In order to reverse this behaviour, you could use a **lazy quantifier**, as explained in this post: [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers/5319978#5319978). So you have to add an extra `?` after a quantifier to attempt a match with as less as it can consume. To make your greedy construct lazy, use `[^\s]+?`.

> some containing string `http://www.example.com/subfolder/name.pdf`
>   or `/subfolder/name.pdf`
>
> > But how to replace the pattern with another pattern?

As you can see, "`http://www.example.com`" is optional. You can make a part of your pattern optional with a `(?:group)` and a `?` quantifier.

Pattern with an optional group:

```regex
(?:http://www\.example\.com)?/(\S+?)\.pdf
```

- Don't forget to escape the dots, as they have a special meaning in regex.
- Notice I used `\S` (capital "S") instead of `[^\s]` (they are both *exactly* the same).

One more thing, you may consider adding some boundaries in your pattern. I suggest using `(?<!\w)` (not preceded by a word character) and `\b` a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid a match as part of another word (as I commented in your question).

### Regex:

```regex
(?<!\w)(?:http://www\.example\.com)?/(\S+?)\.pdf\b
```

### Code:

```php
$re = "@(?<!\\w)(?:http://www\\.example\\.com)?/(\\S+?)\\.pdf\\b@i"; 
$str = "some containing string http://www.example.com/subfolder/name.pdf
        or /subfolder/name.pdf
        <a href=\"/pdf/subdir/name.pdf\">clickhere</a>
        <a href=\"/pdf/subdir/name.pdf\">2nd PDF</a>"; 
$subst = "/wp-content/uploads/old/$1.pdf"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[Test in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aL1eY4/1)

Answer (score 0):

A sandbox example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc47b98d16981b786cf2d573751b6a09a9725b90

```
$array = [
     "https://test.com/url/subfolder/subfolder/file.pdf",
     "https://test.com/url/subfolder1/subfolder/file.pdf",
     "/url/subfolder3/subfolder3/files.xml",
     "/url/subfolder/subfolder/file.pdf"
];

function setwpUrl($urls, $prepend) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
        preg_match_all("/(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)?(.*)/", $urls[$i], $out);
        $urls[$i] = $prepend . $out[2][0];
    }
    return $urls;
}

$newUrls = setwpUrl($array, "/wp-content/uploads/old");

var_dump($newUrls);
```