# Java - all substring for a given regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a pattern like the following

```
API:ADD|TYPE:ABC...MATCH:TRUE

[LOTS OF OTHER LOG LINES]

API:ADD|TYPE:ABC...MATCH:TRUE

[LOTS OF OTHER LOG LINES]

API:ADD|TYPE:DEF...MATCH:TRUE
```

I tried the following regex:

```
(API:.*MATCH:(TRUE|FALSE))

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(i + " occurence");
    i++;
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

**It matches from first "API" to last "TRUE" and hence only one substring is returned!** I want three substrings (in this scenario) starting from "API" till either "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Appreciate your help in this regard.Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
20:31:57    CALL    add     35  
-------------------------------------------------------
20:31:57    REASON  API:ADD|TYPE:ABC|ErrorType:VALIDATION|Error Message:User already has|MATCH:FALSE
```

Comment: You need to know how many groups you want to capture with regex.  Do you expect that you will have a fixed number?

Comment: How are you reading the input?. Line by line?. or all those lines are in one String?.

Comment: Please show us an entire sample line along with what you want to extract.

Comment: I receive it as plain text from HTML response and have the entire content in a String. It can be any number of times - wherever the pattern occurs in the String,need them in a list.

Comment: `.*` wouldn't match across new lines so I believe OP has buffered the content into a string without the new lines.

Comment: @user104309 If you print out the HTML response do you see any new lines?

Comment: You need to show us an entire line so we know what to work with here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see my edit. I guess all new lines are removed while storing in String (jsoup)

Comment: How are you reading in this log file?  From your example, it appears that you are reading in all 3 lines into a single string.  If this be the case, then the regex isn't the problem.  Please clarify this point for us.

Comment: @user104309 The solution is very simple. If you (or jsoup) aren't preserving new lines use `.*?`, otherwise make sure the newlines are not stripped and your current regex should then work without any issues provided your pattern never occurs more than once per line.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy quantifier `.*?` and the *regex* will start matching as little as possible.

```
(API:.*?MATCH:(TRUE|FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `.*` which is a *greedy* quantifier.

You should try to use `.*?` which is *reluctant* -- that means that it matches the smallest possible substring.

For more info about *greedy* vs. *reluctant* see the excellent answers here:
[Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)