# Find longest repeated substring with matched parentheses in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, pattern-matching

Consider a set of strings as follows:

```
aa(bb(c)dd)
aeeff(bb(cd)eee)
(bb(c)dd)(bb(cd(eee
```

Even though the longest repeated non-overlapping substring is `(bb(cd)eee` (10 chars), the longest repeated substring *with matched parentheses* is `(bb(c)ee)` (9 chars).

I can easily [find the longest non-overlapping repeated substring](http://learnruby.com/examples/ruby-quiz-153.shtml), but how can this be extended to matching parentheses?

Comment: What is a "repeated substring"?

Comment: What is a "repeated substring"? The question is not clear.

Comment: @sawa it's literally the first result on google https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Longest_repeated_substring_problem

Comment: And in what sense is `(bb(cd)eee` repeated substring following the definition?

Comment: It appears in both lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want the longest string within a single line that begins with `"("` and ends with `")"` and contains "balanced parentheses". In addition, the substring is to be a "repeated" substring, but that has not been defined, so I've disregarded that requirement.

`balanced_parens?` (below) is from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675974/how-to-separate-a-string-by-perens-without-losing-the-perens-ruby/35679235#35679235).

```
def longest_balanced(str)
  str.lines.map { |s| longest_by_line(s.chomp) }.max_by(&:size)
end 

def longest_by_line(str)
  str.size.downto(1).find do |n|
    str.each_char.each_cons(n) do |a|
      s = a.join
      return s if (s =~ /\A\(.*\)\z/)  && balanced_parens?(s)
    end
  end
  nil
end

def balanced_parens?(str)
  pstr = str.gsub(/[^()]/,"")
  while pstr.gsub!("()", "")
  end
  pstr.empty?
end

str =<<_
aa(bb(c)dd)
aeeff(bb(cd)eee)
(bb(c)dd)(bb(cd(eee
_

longest_balanced str
  #=> "(bb(cd)eee)"
```

Comment: This can be easily combined with the longest repeated substring function mentioned in the question, so I'm accepting even though it does not fully answer the question.

Comment: I somehow missed the link in the question. At that link there is [this link](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz153.html) to the original question. I'm still not clear on what constitutes the "repeated substring" and therefore its length. For "banana", is the repeated substring "an" (length 2) or "anan" (length 4).  It makes a difference if we are comparing "banananana" and "booboo", for example. Moreover, I assume that "banana)" would be skipped but "(bananana)" would be a candidate. Correct? Once I know I'd be happy to revise my answer. As you say, that should be straightforward.

Comment: For "banana", the longest substring that repeats itself without overlapping would be "an" (length 2).

Comment: So "repeating" means repeats one or more times in a row. "bananananan" contains two repeating substrings, "an" and "anan" and the LRS in "dogdogdog" and "catscats" is "cats". Correct?

Comment: No need to repeat in a row. They can repeat in any order. But yes, these are the correct answers for the examples you gave.