# regex_error. What's wrong with my regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm getting regex_error for some reason. I also tried it the regular way of using escape characters (this method eliminates the need for escape sequences in c++ 11 by putting R"(something)" )

By the way if anyone was wondering, they are for recognizing lines in xml

When I use a web based regex tester it works fine.

```
string sstart = R"(\w*+(> ? +[^\\])++>)";
string send = R"(.*<\\\w\w[^m-o][^_]++)";
string sdata = R"([^>]++>[^ ]++)";

regex endtag(send);
regex taganddata(sdata);
regex starttag(sstart);
```

Comment: You should include what these regex are trying to match.  I'm having a hard time discerning between metacharacters and literals.

Comment: Regular expressions are not really able to handle nested constructs such as XML.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the thing with the "raw" string literals introduced in C++11, you don't need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of you regular expressions is incorrect because of '++' part.

`.+` matches one or more occurrences. But what do you try to match with `.++` ?

Comment: The second `+` is called possessive quantifier, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840/372239