# Regular expression to split based on /

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
abc123/xyz456/abc/123/aaa/zzz
```

I would like to split it as

```
abc123,  xyz456 and abc/123/aaa/zzz
```

Basically, I want to split and get the first 2 items as separate items and the rest of the items can be combined.

I tried the regex `^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)$` but it gives me the other way around like `zzz`, `aaa` and `abc123/xyz456/abc/123`.

Is there a way to get this parsed from left to right instead of right to left? or any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix will be to modify the first two `.*` to `.*?` to make the first two `.*` lazy (that is, match up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpattern):

```
^(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*)$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7h5Ogh/1)

Else, use negated character class `[^\/]` that matches any char but `/`:

```
^([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/7h5Ogh/2)

Note that `*` quantifier matches *zero or more* occurrences of the quantified subpattern, you need to replace it with `+` (*one or more occurrences*) if you need to match at least one.

Note that the last `.*` can remain as is, a greedy pattern, as it is at the pattern end and will match as many chars (other than line break chars) as possible, up to the string end. Turning it to `.*?` (i.e. `.*?$`) makes no sense as it will slow down matching.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still have a question for my own understanding -  what does ? do here on the first example?

Comment: Lazy version of the `.*` quantifier. The `.*?` matches up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpattern(s). If `.*` grabs the whole string and then backtracks to accommodate text for the subsequent subpatterns, the lazy pattern is first skipped, and all subsequent subpatterns are tried first. If there is a fail, the lazily quantified pattern is *expanded*, i.e. matches one char if it can, and again the subsequent subpatterns are tried. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5319978/3832970).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)$
```