# How to match a specified pattern with multiple possibilities

Tags: linux, sed

I have a request to replace the pattern `A.*D` with `E.*E`. however my string have multiple combinations to meet this pattern, like `bAcDAccDAccccD`. if I just use the normal way to replace, I can't get my expected result, i.e., `bEcEEccEEccccE`:

`echo 'bAcDAccDAccccD'|sed 's/A\(.*\)D/E\1E/g'` --> `bEcDAccDAccccE`.

How to solve such problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is greedy quantifier(See [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)). It will try to match as much as possible

A simple workaround for given case is

```
$ echo 'bAcDAccDAccccD' | sed 's/A\([^D]*\)D/E\1E/g'
bEcEEccEEccccE
```

`[^D]*` will match only non `D` characters, whereas `.*` will match any character, including `D`