# Remove string between dash (-) and the first dot (.)

Tags: sed

I have many web addresses which are including some special interface names, which I would like to remove. Examples:

`aaaaaaa-INT1.aaaa.aaaa.com`
`bbbbbbb-INT2.bbbb.bbbb.com`
`ccccccc-INT.cccc.cccc.com`

So my expected result after sed should be:

`aaaaaaa.aaaa.aaaa.com`
`bbbbbbb.bbbb.bbbb.com`
`ccccccc.cccc.cccc.com`

I have tried this, but it doesnt work:

`sed 's/-.*^.//'`

Any suggestion please?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650926/how-to-match-a-specified-pattern-with-multiple-possibilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the first dash and everything before the first period:

```
$ sed 's/-[^.]*//' file
aaaaaaa.aaaa.aaaa.com
bbbbbbb.bbbb.bbbb.com
ccccccc.cccc.cccc.com
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `sed` may help you on same too.

```
sed 's/\([^-]*\)-\([^.]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With `awk`.

```
awk -F"." '{sub(/-.*/,"",$1)} 1' OFS="."   Input_file
```