# How to replace only last match in a line with sed?

Tags: sed, replace, text-processing

With `sed`, I can replace the first match in a line using

```
sed 's/pattern/replacement/'
```

And all matches using

```
sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

How do I replace only the **last** match, regardless of how many matches there are before it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy pasting from something I've posted elsewhere:

```sh
$ # replacing last occurrence
$ # can also use sed -E 's/:([^:]*)$/-\1/'
$ echo 'foo:123:bar:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):/\1-/'
foo:123:bar-baz
$ echo '456:foo:123:bar:789:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):/\1-/'
456:foo:123:bar:789-baz
$ echo 'foo and bar and baz land good' | sed -E 's/(.*)and/\1XYZ/'
foo and bar and baz lXYZ good
$ # use word boundaries as necessary - GNU sed
$ echo 'foo and bar and baz land good' | sed -E 's/(.*)\band\b/\1XYZ/'
foo and bar XYZ baz land good

$ # replacing last but one
$ echo 'foo:123:bar:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):(.*:)/\1-\2/'
foo:123-bar:baz
$ echo '456:foo:123:bar:789:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):(.*:)/\1-\2/'
456:foo:123:bar-789:baz

$ # replacing last but two
$ echo '456:foo:123:bar:789:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):((.*:){2})/\1-\2/'
456:foo:123-bar:789:baz
$ # replacing last but three
$ echo '456:foo:123:bar:789:baz' | sed -E 's/(.*):((.*:){3})/\1-\2/'
456:foo-123:bar:789:baz
```

Further Reading:

- [Buggy behavior if word boundaries is used inside a group with quanitifiers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579889/why-doesnt-this-sed-command-replace-the-3rd-to-last-and) - for example: `echo 'it line with it here sit too' | sed -E 's/with(.*\bit\b){2}/XYZ/'` fails
- [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)
- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [sed manual: Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions)

Answer (score 7):

A fun way to do this, is to use [`rev`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rev.1.html) to reverse the characters of each line and write your sed replacement backwards.

```
rev input_file | sed 's/nrettap/tnemecalper/' | rev
```

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)pattern/\1replacement/' file
```

Use greed to swallow up the pattern space and then regexp engine will step back through the line and find the first match i.e. the last match.

Comment: There is nothing GNU-specific here; this should work with any `sed`.