# Java takes excessively long to determine whether a string matches with String.matches

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression which matches any characters at the beginning ending with text in parenthesis `"Hi (Stackoverflow)"`.

When I enter this text to be matched, the program just keeps running.

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]+([\\s]*[\\w]*)*\\([\\w]+\\)"
String text = "Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s)"
String text2 = "Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s) sdsd"

System.out.println(text.matches(pattern)) - it works
System.out.println(text2.matches(pattern)) - never ending story
```

What is wrong?

Comment: add `\\s*` before the escaped opening round bracket.

Comment: Also, remove all the useless square brackets around character class shorthands and change `([\\s]*[\\w]*)*` to `(?>\\s+\\w+)*` or better  `(?:\\s+\\w+)*+` *(The idea is to be more constrictive to avoid a *catastrophic backtracking*).

Comment: What is the expected result for `Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s) sdsd`? No match or `Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s)`? If no match, you need to use `matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\s+\\w+)*+\\(\\w+\\)")`.

Comment: What means this ?: However, it doesnt work. When I enter ^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*\w*)*\(\w+\) then I can match text which is not ending with right bracket. I tried to enter char $ at the end of regex and it works now. But it is very strange...

Comment: I need the text to be only in this format "Any string ending with text inside brackets. Nothing else."

Answer (score 1):

The second one takes long (or at least can take long, depending on the implementation) thanks to the `*`'s in your regex.

Your regex starts off trying to match like this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+   \s* \w*      \s* \w*   \s* \w* \( \w+ \) [unmatched]
Asdadasdasd     sadsdsad     sdasd     X   (  s   )  sdsd
```

At this point you might expect it to say "okay, doesn't match, we're done".

But this is not what it does.

Instead, it will [backtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) in an attempt to find a match that would work (since it's not all that easy for a computer to figure out that backtracking will be a waste of time in this case).

Where it previously matched the second `\w*` to `sdasd`, it will now try 1 less character, i.e. `sdas`, and then it will add another `\s*\w*` which will match 0 characters for `\s*` and `d` for `\w*`.

```
[a-zA-Z]+   \s* \w*      \s* \w*  \s* \w* \s* \w* \( \w+ \) [unmatched]
Asdadasdasd     sadsdsad     sdas X   d       X   (  s   )  sdsd
```

This also won't work, so it will instead try `sda` and then `sd`, which won't work and lead it to splitting that up further to `sda`, `s` and `d`.

```
[a-zA-Z]+   \s* \w*      \s* \w*  \s* \w* \s* \w* \( \w+ \) [unmatched]
Asdadasdasd     sadsdsad     sda  X   sd      X   (  s   )  sdsd

[a-zA-Z]+   \s* \w*      \s* \w*  \s* \w* \s* \w* \s* \w* \( \w+ \) [unmatched]
Asdadasdasd     sadsdsad     sda  X   s   X   d       X   (  s   )  sdsd
```

And so on, until each `\w` is just matching one character.

*PS:* The above is not necessarily *exactly* what it does, it's more intended to give a basic idea of what happens.

*PPS:* Used `\` instead of `\\` for brevity.

#### How do you fix it?

There are a few ways to fix it.

The one requiring the least changes is perhaps to use `(\\s*\\w*)*+` instead - `*+` makes the `*` [possessive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers), which prevents it from backtracking at all (which is in line with what we want here).

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\\s*\\w*)*+\\(\\w+\\)
```

What would also work is to use `\\s+` instead of `\\s*`, although this would lead to some slightly different behaviour (specifically that 0-9 can no longer appear before the first space, which can be fixed by adding `\\w*` before your brackets).

This fixes it because we can no longer match 0 characters for `\\s`, which prevents a lot of work we would've otherwise done while backtracking.

```
   ^[a-zA-Z]+(\\s+\\w*)*\\(\\w+\\)
OR ^[a-zA-Z]+\\w*(\\s+\\w*)*\\(\\w+\\)
```

I'd also recommend removing the `+` from the `[a-zA-Z]` in either case, since this is already covered by the `\\w*` (thus doesn't change what the regex matches) and (in my opinion) makes the desired behaviour of the regex clearer when looking at it.

*PS:* `[\\s]*` is equivalent to `\\s*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+([\\s]*[\\w]*)*\\([\\w]+\\)");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s)";
    String text2 = "Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s) sdsd (k) ssdd";

    match(text);
    match(text2);
}


private static void match(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s)
Asdadasdasd sadsdsad sdasd (s)
sdsd (k)
```