# Sed Regular Expression affecting content after the Regex

Tags: regex, sed, non-greedy

I have an HTML file containing the following text:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Test</title><base href="/"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"></head><body>test</body></html>
```

And I run this `sed` command against it:

```
sed -i -e "s:<base href\s*=\s*\".*\"\s*>:<base href=\"/apps/test/\">:g" /tmp/test/index.html
```

I'd expect for that just to replace `<base href="/">` with `<base href="/apps/test/">` and leave the rest alone, but it ends up affecting content after the regex:

```
 <!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Test</title><base href="/apps/test/"></head><body>test</body></html>
```

It ended up removing the entire `meta` tag found after the regex. Am I just not doing the regex right?

```
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

Comment: enjoy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags .. see also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers (and sed doesn't support lazy quantifiers)

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regexes is a dangerous proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/519360). Doing it "right" requires implementing a full-on HTML parser in regex(es), and while that's technically possible, it's ill advised. …That said, `s:<base\s[^>]*>:<base href='/apps/test'>:gi` should work fine as long as the `<base>` tag isn't multi-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `*` is greedy, the `.*` in `=\s*\".*\"\s*>` matches to the furthest right `>` available.

You can use single quotes around your command so you don't have to use `\"` for double quotes. Then, instead of `".*"`, you can use `"[^"]*"`, which only matches to the next double quote.

This would make your command into

```sh
sed 's:<base href\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*>:<base href="/apps/test/">:g'
```

However, manipulating HTML with sed and regexes is eternally brittle and will break at the first possible opportunity. You could use an XML/HTML parser such as xmllint, see Roman's answer; an alternative are the W3C [HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) with their `hxpipe` and `hxunpipe` commands.

These commands parse your HTML and turn it into a format easily processed with sed, awk & friends, then turn it back into HTML:

```
$ hxpipe infile.html
!html "" 
(html
(head
Acharset CDATA utf-8
(meta
(title
-Test
)title
Ahref CDATA /
(base
Aname CDATA viewport
Acontent CDATA width=device-width,initial-scale=1
(meta
)head
(body
-test
)body
)html
-\n
```

so to turn the `/` in the `href` for the `base` tag into `/apps/test/`, we could do this:

```
$ hxpipe infile.html \
    | sed '/Ahref CDATA/{N;/\n(base$/s|\(CDATA\) .*|\1 /apps/test/|}' \
    | hxunpipe
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Test</title><meta href="/apps/test/" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"></head><body>test</body></html>
```

where the sed command

```sh
sed '/Ahref CDATA/{N;/\n(base$/s|\(CDATA\) .*|\1 /apps/test/|}'
```

or, better readable

```
/Ahref CDATA/ {                                # If line matches this
    N                                          # Append next line
    /\n(base$/ s|\(CDATA\) .*|\1 /apps/test/|  # If in base tag, replace href
}
```

in a more or less robust fashion makes your change.

Answer (score 2):

The only right way for processing xml/html data is to use xml/html parsers.

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet fo -R -H /tmp/test/index.html | xmlstarlet ed -O -u '//base/@href' -v '/apps/test/'
```

The output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <base href="/apps/test/"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
  </head>
  <body>test</body>
</html>
```

---

To modify the file in-place add `-L` option: `xmlstarlet ed -L -u ....`