# Replace the first occurrence with sed

Tags: regex, sed

As the example below, I want to keep only the word before the **first**
'John'.

However, the pattern I applied seems to replace John from the end to the head. So I need to call sed twice.

How could I find the correct way?

```
PATTERN="I am John, you are John also"
OUTPUT=$( echo "$PATTERN" | sed -r "s/(^.*)([ \t]*John[ ,\t]*)(.*$)/\1/" )
echo "$OUTPUT"
OUTPUT=$( echo "$OUTPUT" | sed -r "s/(^.*)([ \t]*John[ ,\t]*)(.*$)/\1/" )
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

My expectation is only call sed one time. Since if "John" appears several times it will be a trouble.

By the procedure above, it will generate output as:

Firstly it matches & trims the word after the final John; then the first John.

> I am John, you are
>
> I am

I want to execute one time and get

> I am

Comment: Try [`awk -F'[[:blank:]]*John[[:blank:]]*' '{ print $1 }'`](http://rextester.com/GWJ61030)

Comment: Don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` variables in the shell. Those tend to be used for system stuff (e.g. `HOME`) or have a special meaning to the shell itself (e.g. `PATH`, `RANDOM`).

Comment: @chang jc, please mention always expected output in your post too.

Comment: @chang, I'd suggest to look up about greediness.. `.*` will try to match as much as possible and then backtrack from end if needed... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers might help..

Answer (score 2):

Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
echo "I am John, you are John also" | sed 's/ John.*//'
```

Or with variables.

```
pattern="I am John, you are John also"
output=$(echo "$pattern" | sed 's/John.*//')
```

Comment: Simple and accurate ++

Comment: `sed 's/ John.*//'` would be better

Comment: It does not return only the first word

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 `echo "I am John, you are John also" | sed 's/ John.*//'` => `I am`, it's two words

Comment: @Sundeep "_ I want to keep only the word before the first 'John'._", well seems clear to me - edit, ok since he edited, it's not anymore :p

Comment: @Arount, I believe this one will work for OP as per OP's output.

Comment: why  sed 's/ John.*//'  match the first but sed -r "s/(^.*)([ \t]*John[ ,\t]*)(.*$)/\1/" ) matches the final?  I cannot understand...

Comment: @changjc, simple, if you DO NOT want the part in anywhere of your script after first occurrence of john then why to save it unnecessary in memory of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to use the `grep` command in `Perl` mode:

```
echo "I am John, you are John also" | grep -oP '^(?:(?!John).)*';
I am 
#there will be a space at the end
echo "I am John, you are John also" | grep -oP '^(?:(?!John).)*(?=\s)';
I am
#there is no space at the end
```

Regex explanations:

```
^(?:(?!John).)*
```

This will accept all characters from the beginning of the lines until it reaches the first `John`.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jXEnam/2)

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
s="I am John, you are John also and there is another John there"
awk '{ sub(/[[:space:]]+John.*/, "") }1' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
I am
```

Comment: I paid attention to OP's input that has only a single space :)

Comment: @anubhava, We professionals should tend to unified solutions to prevent that often-used comments like *"This won't work if .... or this won't work in case of"*. The difference is that the posters need the solution for theirselfs  but we provide a solution for the community. That's all