# sed to replace pattern in second column for multiple times

Tags: unix, sed

New to sed and trying to get the following done, but completely stuck:
I am trying to replace a pattern with sed in the second column. This pattern is occuring multiple times.

I have:

```
Gene1 GO:0000045^biological_process^autophagosome assembly`GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm
Gene2 GO:0000030^molecular_function^mannosyltransferase activity`GO:0006493^biological_process^protein O-linked glycosylation`GO:0016020^cellular_component^membrane
```

I want to get:

```
Gene1 GO:0000045,GO:0005737
Gene2 GO:0000030,GO:0006493,GO:0016020
```

So getting rid of all the descriptive parts and use "," as the delimiter. I choose to use sed because I thought to easily recognize the pattern between ^ and  `. But instead it removes all first GO terms.

Code:

```
sed -E 's/(^)'.+'(`)/,/g'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, shown as two steps for illustration

```sh
$ # showing how to remove from ^ to ` and replace with ,
$ sed 's/\^[^`]*`/,/g' ip.txt
Gene1 GO:0000045,GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm
Gene2 GO:0000030,GO:0006493,GO:0016020^cellular_component^membrane

$ # removing remaining data from ^ to end of line as well
$ sed 's/\^[^`]*`/,/g; s/\^.*//' ip.txt
Gene1 GO:0000045,GO:0005737
Gene2 GO:0000030,GO:0006493,GO:0016020
```

- since `^` is a metacharacter, use `\^` to match it literally
- `` [^`]* `` will match zero or more non `` ` `` characters
- don't use `` \^.*` ``, this will delete from first ^ to last backtick in the line due to [greedy nature of quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\^[^`]*//g' -e 's/`/,/g' your_file
```

First command remove (substitute by nothing) any character except `` ` `` behind `^` (included)

Second substitute `` ` `` by `,`

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the individual fields and then operating on each of those would probably be more useful long-term than just identifying parts of each line with regexps:

```
$ awk -F'^' -v OFS=',' '{print NR") "$0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "\t"i") "$i}' file
1) Gene1 GO:0000045^biological_process^autophagosome assembly`GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm
        1) Gene1 GO:0000045
        2) biological_process
        3) autophagosome assembly`GO:0005737
        4) cellular_component
        5) cytoplasm
2) Gene2 GO:0000030^molecular_function^mannosyltransferase activity`GO:0006493^biological_process^protein O-linked glycosylation`GO:0016020^cellular_component^membrane
        1) Gene2 GO:0000030
        2) molecular_function
        3) mannosyltransferase activity`GO:0006493
        4) biological_process
        5) protein O-linked glycosylation`GO:0016020
        6) cellular_component
        7) membrane
```

.

```
$ awk -F'^' -v OFS=',' '{out=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (sub(/.*`/,"",$i)) out=out OFS $i; print out}' file
Gene1 GO:0000045,GO:0005737
Gene2 GO:0000030,GO:0006493,GO:0016020
```