# Replace text between two symbols across the full string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How to Replace the string inside the semicolon and the comma to "X" using R regex.

Input:
 `My name : Harry, Age : 23, Address : London,`

Output:
`My name : X, Age : X, Address : X,`

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried and add a label with relevant programming language or tool.

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub(": .*?,", ": X,", "My name : Harry, Age : 23, Address : London,")

#[1] "My name : X, Age : X, Address : X,"
```

Comment: while this answer works, and although it is not to the best question, I feel like the answer could still do with some explanation. In R's help guidance for regex the use of `?` is explained as "The preceding item is optional and will be matched at most once." I do not understand how this causes the `.*` part to limit itself to its shortest option.

Comment: @AaronHayman Adding the question mark effectively causes `.*` to be reluctant as opposed to greedy. There's a nice discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers).

Answer (score 0):

you can use gsub

gsub( "[a-zA-Z0-9]+[,]",": X, ","My name : Harry, Age : 23, Address : Londo")

Comment: Output for above code would be : ```"My name : X, Harry, Age : X, 23, Address : X, Londo"```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gsub`, This performs greedy search substitution.

```
gsub(':[^,]+,',': X,',"My name : Harry, Age : 23, Address : London,")
## [1] "My name : X, Age : X, Address : X,"
```

The regex will look for sequences that match the discription in the first argument.

`[^,]+` matches to a sequence that contains no commas, this ensures that only the next comma can be considered as part of the overall sequence.