# sed selects last occurence instead of first

Tags: sed, match

I only want to select the first occurrence of a pattern on the line, e.g. the '53.0' instead I get:

```
$ echo  "Core 0: +53.0°C (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)" |
  sed -n 's/.*+\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'
```

which, for me, prints:  100.0 when I expected: 53.0.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

What am I missing?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
echo  "Core 0: +53.0°C (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)" | 
sed 's/[^+]*+\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

OR in case you don't want `°` in output then try following.

```
echo  "Core 0: +53.0°C (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)" |  
sed 's/[^+]*+\([^°]*\).*/\1/'
```

***Explanation of above code:***

I have used `sed`'s capability of saving matched regex into temp buffer memory and given it a reference as `\1` to print it later.

Following explanation is only for explaining purposes  to run code use above code please.

```
sed '          ##Starting sed program here.
s              ##Using s option for substitution method by sed on Lines of Input_file.
/[^+]*+        ##Using regex to have till 1st occurrence of + here.
\([^ ]*\)      ##Using memory buffer saving capability of sed to save matched regex in it.
               ##Have used regex to match everything till occurrence of space. Which should catch 1st temperature.
.*             ##Mentioning .* to match all rest line.
/\1/'          ##Now substituting whole line with 1st buffer matched value.
```

***Explanation of why OP's code not working:*** Since OP is using `.*+` in his/her attempt which is a [GREEDY match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840) so hence it is matching the last occurrence of `+` thus it is giving last temperature value.

Note: Added link provided by Sundeep sir in comments for Greedy match understanding.

Comment: Both worked so thank you very much, especially for the supporting explanation.

Comment: @RogerM, your welcome, you can select this answer as correct answer too, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple to do with `awk` (no need for complex regex)

```
echo  "Core 0: +53.1°C (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)" | awk '{print $3+0}'
53.1
```

Print the third field `$3`, then the `+0` is used to get only the digits, it trims of `°C`