# Greedy behaviour of grep

Tags: regex, grep, regex-greedy, posix-ere

I thought that in regular expressions, the "greediness" applies to quantifiers rather than matches as a whole. However, I observe that

```
grep -E --color=auto 'a+(ab)?' <(printf "aab")
```

returns **aab** rather than **aa**b.

The same applies to sed.
On the other hand, in pcregrep and other tools, it is really the quantifier that is greedy. 
Is this a specific behaviour of grep?

N.B. I checked both 
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD and grep (GNU grep) 3.1

Comment: Related: [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840)

Comment: ok, I understood the question better now, `echo 'aab' | grep -P 'a+(ab)?'` highlights `aa` whereas `echo 'aab' | grep -E 'a+(ab)?'` highlights `aab` meaning it optional `ab` matched even though it wasn't required.. I think it is because of longest match wins.. for example, `echo 'aab' | grep -E 'a+|a+b'` highlights `aab` because that's the longest match whereas `echo 'aab' | grep -P 'a+|a+b'` highlights `aa` because in PCRE, alternation precedence is left to right for matches starting from same location

Comment: yes, I had read somewhere about longest match too. But it conflicted "greedy quantifier". I did not realize this was yet another point where POSIX regex and some others differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the description of term ***matched***](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01_02), POSIX states that

> The search for a matching sequence starts at the beginning of a string and stops when the first sequence matching the expression is found, where "first" is defined to mean "begins earliest in the string". **If the pattern permits a variable number of matching characters and thus there is more than one such sequence starting at that point, the longest such sequence is matched.**

This statement clearly anwers your question. The string `aab` contains two substrings beginning at the same position matching the ERE `a+(ab)?`; these are `aa` and `aab`. The latter is the longest, thus it's matched.

Comment: So, the statement that quantifiers are greedy by default in regex does not apply to POSIX regex, but only to PCRE based tools?

Comment: @JosephStack I don't know anything about PCRE, but probably yes

Comment: thanks. Many places where I read that "quantifiers are greedy" did not make clear to what regex flavour it applies to...