# regex for either of two substrings but prefer the longer substring

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to match either `cde` or `de` but prefer `cde` if present. How can this be done in `sed`? 
e.g.

```
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -r 's/^.*(cde|de).*$/\1/' 
de
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -r 's/^.*(de|cde).*$/\1/' 
de
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -r 's/^.*(c?de).*$/\1/' 
de
```

None of the above worked, since I want to output `cde` rather than `de`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137763/greedy-behaviour-of-grep

Comment: This might help: `sed -r 's/^.*[^c](c?de).*$/\1/'`

Comment: @Cyrus good idea, modified to `sed -E 's/^(.*[^c]|^)(c?de).*$/\2/'` incase there are no characters before the match

Comment: @Sundeep: Yeah, I hadn't considered that case at all.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` doesn't support non-greedy, and quantifiers will match leftmost longest, so optional `c` in this case isn't possible with regex alone. You could use branch commands for this particular example.

```
$ # tested with GNU sed, syntax might differ for other implementations
$ # t command here will start next cycle if first s command succeeds
$ # so, the second s command will execute only if first one fails
$ printf 'abdef\nabcdef\n' | sed 's/.*cde.*/cde/; t; s/.*de.*/de/'
de
cde
```

You could also use `grep` if it supports `-o` option (print only matching portions)

```
$ printf 'abdef\nabcdef\n' | grep -oE 'c?de'
de
cde
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl supports non-greedy:

```
echo "abcdef" | perl -p -e 's/^.*?(c?de).*$/\1/'
```

Output:

```
cde
```