# How to find the first occurrence of sub-strings not ended with specified characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm gonna select the first occurrence of an only-alphabet string which is not ended by any of the characters `"."`, `":"` and `";"`

For example:

```
"float a bbc 10" --> "float"
"float.h" --> null
"float:: namespace" --> "namesapace"
"float;" --> null
```

I came up with the regex `\G([A-z]+)(?![:;\.])` but it only ignores the character before the banned characters, while I need it to skip all string before banned characters.

Comment: Whether the first or all occurrences, it is done with the code. The regex you need is `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]++(?![:;.])` or `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+\b(?![:;.])`. Well, you may as well  use `^.*?\K(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]++(?![:;.])` (PCRE) or get Group 1 in `^.*?(?<!\S)([A-Za-z]+)\b(?![:;.])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, It works, I'm using the Perl and `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]++(?![:;.])` worked perfectly. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]++(?![:;.])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/moncuN/1). Make sure not to use the `g` modifier to get the first match only.

One of the main trick here is to use a [possessive `++` quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers/33582669) to match all consecutive letters and check for `:`, `;` or `.` only once right after the last of the matched letters.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\S)` - either whitespace or start of string should immediately precede the current location
- `[A-Za-z]++`  - 1+ letters matched possessively allowing no backtracking into the pattern
- `(?![:;.])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `;`, `:` or `.` immediately to the right of the current location.