# Why is my regex putting a character in a different capture group than what I am expecting?

Tags: regex-group

I have the given strings:

```
bar"{foo}"bar
bar{foo}bar
```

I am trying to get both the first and third capture group to be just `bar`.  The second capture group should be `{foo}` both with and without quotes for each match respectively.

I have the following regex:

```
(^.*)("?\{.*\}"?)(.*$)
```

With these results:

```
Match 1
Full match.  bar"{foo}"bar
Group 1.     bar"
Group 2.     {foo}"
Group 3.     bar

Match 2
Full match.  bar{foo}bar
Group 1.     bar
Group 2.     {foo}
Group 3.     bar
```

Why are the `"` characters not both in the second group?  I do not understand why it would be in the first if I am specifically calling it out in the second group.  Do I need to tell the first group to ignore it or use it as a right bound?

Comment: I am on a phone, so I give just some hints: in Match1 Group1 you use .* which consumes the " character (. means any) , so it gets matched, because following "? matches zero or one ", thus matching 0, because " was consumed by first capturing group. Try debugging pattern on regex101

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thank, you,  you are correct. I realized my issue upon posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was finishing writing this question I realized the problem I had.  I needed to use a reluctant quantifier so the first group would not grab the `"` before the next group had a shot.

Here is the small correction - I added `.*?` (reluctant) instead of `.*` (greedy):

```
(^.*?)("?\{.*\}"?)(.*$)
```

Good explanation here: [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)