# Use sed (or similar) to remove anything between repeating patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, non-greedy

I'm essentially trying to "tidy" a lot of data in a CSV. I don't need any of the information that's in "quotes".

Tried `sed 's/".*"/""/'` but it removes the commas if there's more than one section together.

I would like to get from this:

```
1,2,"a",4,"b","c",5
```

To this:

```
1,2,,4,,,5
```

Is there a sed wizard who can help? :)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers wrt why your attempt failed

Comment: `sed 's/"."//g' file`

Comment: All 3 solutions work - thank you all. Just found a curveball that in some lines, there are line breaks - just need to remove those and I'm sorted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"//g' file > newfile
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/mUO7Mj):

```
s='1,2,"a",4,"b","c",5'
sed 's/"[^"]*"//g' <<< "$s"
# => 1,2,,4,,,5
```

**Details**

The `"[^"]*"` pattern matches `"`, then 0 or more characters other than `"`, and then `"`. The matches are removed since RHS is empty. `g` flag makes it match all occurrences on each line.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~s1){$i=""}}} 1' Input_file
```

Non-one liner form of solution is:

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~s1){
      $i=""
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Detailed explanation:***

```
awk -v s1="\"" '         ##Starting awk program from here and mentioning variable s1 whose value is "
BEGIN{                   ##Starting BEGIN section of this code here.
  FS=OFS=","             ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma(,) here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){    ##Starting a for loop which traverse through all fields of current line.
    if($i~s1){           ##Checking if current field has " in it if yes then do following.
      $i=""              ##Nullifying current field value here.
    }
  }
}
1                        ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
'  Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl:

```
perl -p -e 's/".*?"//g' file
```

`?` forces `*` to be non-greedy.

Output:

```
1,2,,4,,,5
```