# Retrieve sections from string using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like `"members[value eq\"2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646\"].displayName"`, where i was trying to retrieve **members, string in bracket, and displayname**.

I tried this,  `matchObj = re.match( r"(.*)\[([.*]+)\?](.*?)", line, re.M|re.I)`
where string in bracket and last string(after `.`) are optional (this part `"[value eq\"2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646\"].displayName"`).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: need more example and description, anyways, does `re.search(r"(\w+)(?:\[[^]]*\])?(?:\.\w+)?", line)[0]` work?

Comment: ```re.search(r"(\w+)(\[[^]]*\])?(\.\w+)?", line)```, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\w+)(\[[^]]*\])?(\.\w+)?
```

- `\w` will match any word character (alphabets, numbers and underscore)

  - use `[a-zA-Z]` to match only alphabets, `[a-zA-Z\d]` to match digits as well
- `\[[^]]*\]` will match `[` followed by non `]` characters followed by `]`

  - `(\[[^]]*\])?` makes it optional for this entire pattern
- `\.\w+` will match `.` and word characters

If you use `(.*)` instead of `(\w+)` the greediness of `.*` will make it to match everything as the next two are optional. See also: [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers)