# How to pick useful information within curly braces from a text file using a python script?

Tags: python, regex, string, file-handling, string-matching

I have a huge text file that has information stored in this format.

```
someOtherMessage{
              class = "someClass";
      sampleMessage{
                  someValue{
                      someText{
                          someParam = "value";
                          someSymbol = "another_symbol";
                      }; //someText
                  }; //someValue
       }; //sampleMessage
    }; //someOtherMessage

someOtherMessage2{
              class = "someClass2";
      sampleMessage2{
                  someValue2{
                      someText2{
                          someParam = "value2";
                          someSymbol = "another_symbol2";
                      }; //someText2
                  }; //someValue2
       }; //sampleMessage2
    }; //someOtherMessage2
```

I want to iterate over this file using a py script and build a dict(or any other data struct) in the following format.

For eg.

```
dict = {'someOtherMessage': 'someOtherMessage{
              class = "someClass";
      sampleMessage{
                  someValue{
                      someText{
                          someParam = "value";
                          someSymbol = "another_symbol";
                      }; //someText
                  }; //someValue
       }; //sampleMessage
    }; //someOtherMessage',

'someOtherMessage2': 'someOtherMessage2{
          class = "someClass2";
  sampleMessage2{
              someValue2{
                  someText2{
                      someParam = "value2";
                      someSymbol = "another_symbol2";
                  }; //someText2
              }; //someValue2
   }; //sampleMessage2
}; //someOtherMessage2'
}
```

I used the following regex but it picks everything between the first and last curly brace, how can I make it pick just the required ones separately?

[r"(?s){(.*)}"](https://regex101.com/r/eU1Afr/1)

Comment: Will there always be that *'}; //someOtherMessage`\n`someOtherMessage2{'*  new line between any two parts that you want?

Comment: @AKSingh, Yes, actually there can be multiple new lines too!

Comment: `(?s)\{(.*?)\};.*?(\n\n|$)` Try this in where `^` and `$` **do not** match end of each line. In simple words, do not add `m` modifier.

Comment: @AKSingh, Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/eU1Afr/2) out.

Comment: Please remove the `m` modifier. Try https://regex101.com/r/1T7Bey/1.

Comment: @AKSingh, Thanks, My problem is pretty much solved. Just one thing, what's the role of the last group(\n\n|$)?

Comment: I will write an answer to explain it. Is it working properly in the text file?

Comment: @AKSingh, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solution for your problem. *I am assuming you are aware about greedy and lazy quantifiers*. If not, here is a link: [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-qualifiers)

```
(?s)\{(.*?)\};.*?(\n\n|$)
```

---

### Error

In the original regex, `(?s){(.*)}`, you have used *greedy quantifier which matches too much* and hence results in matching something that is not what we want.

If you replace it with a *lazy quantifier*, `(?s){(.*?)}`, *it matches too little* which again results in matching something not desired.

---

### Correction

*In order to specify the correction ending `}` we have to find something to anchor our match*. This is where those *new lines* between that data that is to be obtained comes into play.

```
    }; //someOtherMessage

someOtherMessage2{
```

Here there is a `\n` after that `someOtherMessage` comment and then another `\n` in that new line. So we add

```
`(?s)\{(.*?)\};.*?\n\n`
```

which simply means `{...something here...}...something here...\n\n`.

This regex will still not the ending data since it does not have any `\n` in the end.

```
}; //someOtherMessage2'
}
```

So to match it, *we set `$` to match end of file by removing `m` modifier*. This changes our regex to:

```
 (?s)\{(.*?)\};.*?(\n\n|$)
```

---

I hope I have helped you with your problem. Please do note this is one of the possible solution to your problem. *There is another approach to finding matching nested parenthesis which is also available on SO. However, it might be a bit complex*. Here is one such link: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

If you any other doubt, please do mention them.