# Colregex method in pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to understand how `colRegex` is working in pyspark. How the `colRegex` is choosing between `Col1` and `Col2`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c",  3)], ["Col1", "Col2"])

df.select(df.colRegex("`(Col1)?+.+`")).show()

+----+
|Col2|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
+----+

df.select(df.colRegex("`(Col2)?+.+`")).show()

+----+
|Col1|
+----+
|   a|
|   b|
|   c|
+----+
```

In the above expression I used `"(Col3)?+.+"`. It gives me `Col1` and `Col2`. Can you elaborate what is happening in the regex expression?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually not really about `colRegex`. That function simply selects all the columns that match the provided regex. Spark being written in scala, it relies on scala/java regex implementation.

Indeed:

```scala
scala> "Col1".matches("(Col2)?+.+")
res28: Boolean = true
scala> "Col1".matches("(xxxxx)?+.+")
res28: Boolean = true
scala> "Col2".matches("(Col2)?+.+")
res28: Boolean = false
```

So the question is, how to explain that in java/scala `Col2` is not matched by the regex `(Col2)?+.+`. If we have a look at the [javadoc of the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), we read this:

> **Possessive quantifiers**
>
> `X?+`:    `X`, once or not at all

This post [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-qualifiers) explains nicely what a possessive quantifier is. In a nutshell, it is a greedy quantifier that does not backtrack when it fails. In this case, `Col2` matches `(Col2)?+` and then there is nothing to match with `.+` that requires at least one character.

With `?`, the greedy (usual) quantifier, the matching would backtrack, match `(Col2)?` with nothing and return true because `Col2` matches `.+`.

With `?+` however, the possessive quantifier, it does not backtrack and fails there. This is why `(Col2)?+.+` matches all non empty expressions except `Col2`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Is there any documentation how the regex expression is working in scala.?

Comment: I actually read it and changed my answer entirely :-D Read my answer again, you'll understand everything!

Comment: Hi Manasa, if your problem is solved, can you accept the answer please?