# Back-ticks in DataFrame.colRegex?

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

For PySpark, I find back-ticks enclosing regular expressions for
`DataFrame.colRegex()`
[here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/select-columns-from-pyspark-dataframe),
[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex.html),
and in [this SO
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75219588).  Here is the
example from the `DataFrame.colRegex` doc string:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c",  3)], ["Col1", "Col2"])
df.select(df.colRegex("`(Col1)?+.+`")).show()
+----+
|Col2|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
+----+
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75240179) to the SO question
*doesn't* show back-ticks for Scala.  It refers to the Java
documentation for the [`Pattern`
class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html),
but that doesn't explain back-ticks.

[This page](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php?item=y108/backtick)
indicates the use of back-ticks in Python to represent the string
representation of the adorned variable, but that doesn't apply
to a regular expression.

What is the explanation for the back-ticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back-ticks are used to [delimit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-identifier.html#delimited-identifier) the column name in case it includes special characters. For example, if you had a column called `column-1` and you try

```sql
SELECT column-1 FROM mytable
```

You will probably get a

> non-existent column 'column'

error as the interpreter will treat that as `SELECT (column) - 1 FROM mytable`. Instead, you can delimit the column name with back-ticks to get around that issue:

```sql
SELECT `column-1` FROM mytable
```

Note that the PySpark doc string for `DataFrame.colRegex()` explains the argument as *"column name specified as a regex"*.  It is not just a regular expression that possibly matches *portions* of one or more column names.  In the latter case, back-ticks would be confusing because back-ticks aren't used to delimit portions of a column name.  Therefore, SQL's adornment of entire column names with back-ticks makes sense for `colRegex` because the argument is the matching of an entire column name rather than just a substring.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, especially for the citation.  I find my self running around in circles when I try to track down the right documentation in PySpark.

Comment: @user2153235 no problem - glad to help. I always try to include a citation if I'm referring to the docs...