# What's wrong with this Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex, function

In java, I'm trying to detect strings of the form: optional underline, capital letters, and then curly brackets encasing two parameters. I.e. things like `MAX{1,2}` `FUNC{3,7}` `_POW{9,10}`

I've decided to put off dealing with the parameters until later, so the regex I'm using is:

```
_?[A-Z]+//{.*//}
```

But I'm getting the following error when trying to compile it into a Pattern object:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 9
_?[A-Z]+//{.*//}
         ^
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets in your expression, else they are treated as a repetition operator.  I think you'd want to use `\` for this instead of `//`.

Comment: ...and because you're writing it in the form of a Java string literal, you have to escape the backslash: `"_?[A-Z]+\\{.*\\}"`

Comment: @Alan: Unless you use a "/"->"\" front-end converter to save your sanity. :)

Answer (score 4):

John is correct. But you also don't want to use the `'.*'` greedy-dot-star. Here is a better regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("_?[A-Z]+\\{[^}]+\\}");
```

Note that you do NOT need to escape the curly brace inside a character class. This is fundamental syntax which you need to learn if you want to use regex effectively. See: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - (an hour spent here will pay for itself *many* times over!)

Comment: Small suggestion. To avoid greedy-dot-star, instead of [^}], "Reluctant quantifier (?)" can be used. e.g. ("_?[A-Z]+\\{.*?\\}"). More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant

Comment: @siddagrl - Thanks for the suggestion, but no, `[^}]+` is much more efficient (i.e is faster) than `.*?` and is more accurate as well. To understand why, I highly recommend reading: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"). Cheers!

Comment: Oh! I did not know that. Thanks for sharing. Will have a look.