# Pattern.compile("(.*?):")

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
Pattern.compile("(.*?):")
```

I already did some [research](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) about what it could mean,
but I don't quite get it:

According to the java docs the * would mean 0 or more times,
while ? means once or not at all.

Also, what does the ':' mean?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28.*%3F%29%3A) out.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Nice, but in Java `.` is equivalent to `[^\n\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]`. [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` after greedy operators such as `+` or `*` will make the operator non greedy. Without the `?`, that regex will keep matching all the characters it finds, including the `:`.

As it is, the regex will match any string which happens before the semi colon (`:`). In this case, the semicolon is not a special character. What ever comes before the semicolon, will be thrown into a group, which can be accessed later through a `Matcher` object.

This code snippet will hopefully make things more clear:

```
    String str = "Hello: This is a Test:";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.*?):");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(.*):");
    
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str);
    if (m1.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));            
    }
    
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(str);
    if (m2.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m2.group(1));
    }
```

Yields:

> Hello
>
> Hello: This is a Test

Answer (score 5):

This is called a *reluctant quantifier*. An asterisk and a question mark `*?` together mean "zero or more times, without matching more characters from the input than is needed". This is what prevents the dot `.` expression from matching the subsequent colon `:` in the input.

A better expression to match the same sequence is `[^:]*:`, because it lets you avoid backtracking. Here is a [link to an article explaining why](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance).

Comment: The word is *quantifier*, not *qualifier*: it specifies a quantity.  In fact, you might say the `?` qualifies the quantifier; `*` is normally greedy, but the `?` "weakens" it, making it reluctant or non-greedy.

Comment: @AlanMoore You're right, it is quantifier. I edited the answer to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression means `anthing ending with :` or it could be understood as `anthing till first :`.

Here ':' means nothing. but it complies for pattern `anystring:` will match to this pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think the '?' is redundant and will be applied on '.*'.

':' has no special meaning whatsoever in regexps and will be matched to the characters in the string.

EDIT: dasblinkenlight is be right, if greedy the regexp will try to match as much as they can, and he is right in his suggestion as well.

I found a link which lists greedy vs reluctant: [What is the difference between `Greedy` and `Reluctant` regular expression quantifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant)