# Can't get a match for regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

This is the format/example of the string I want to get data:

```
<span style='display:block;margin-bottom:3px;'><a style='margin:4px;color:#B82933;font-size:120%' href='/cartelera/pelicula/18312'>Español  </a></span><br><span style='display:block;margin-bottom:3px;'><a style='margin:4px;color:#FBEBC4;font-size:120%' href='/cartelera/pelicula/18313'>Subtitulada  </a></span><br>          </div>
```

And this is the regular expression I'm using for it:

```
"pelicula/([0-9]*)'>([\\w\\s]*)</a>"
```

I tested this regular expression in [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), and it turned out OK, it gave me the expected result:

```
group(1) = 18313
group(2) = Subtitulada
```

But when I try to implement that regular expression in Java, it won't match anything. Here's the code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("pelicula/([0-9]*)'>([\\w\\s]*)</a>");              
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);            
            while(matcher.find()){
                    version = matcher.group(2);
                }
            }
```

What's the problem? If the regular expression is already tested, and in that same code I search for more patterns but I'm having trouble with two (I'm showing you here just one). Thank you in advance!

_*EDIT****_*_**

I discovered the problem... If I check the sourcecode of the page it shows everything, but when I try to consume it from Java, it gets another sourcecode. Why? Because this page asks for your city so it can show information about that. I don't know if there's a workaround about that to actually access the information I want, but that's it.

Comment: How do you know that it's not matching?  It looks like all you're doing is assigning the group to a variable (`version`).  There's no output.  Try this in your while loop, instead:  `System.out.println(matcher.group());`

Comment: I do have a System.out.println, but I ommited it in the posted code for clarity.

Comment: _consume from Java, it gets another sourcecode_ ? what and how exactly are you consuming in Java

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is correct but it seems `\w` does not match `ñ`.

I changed the regex to

`"pelicula/([0-9]*)'>(.*?)</a>"`

and it seems to match both the occurrences. 
Here I've used the reluctant `*?` operator to prevent `.*` match all characters in between first `<a>` till last `<\a>`
See [What is the difference between `Greedy` and `Reluctant` regular expression quantifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant) for explanation.

@Bohemian is correct in pointing out that you might need to enable the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag as well if the text in `<a>` has line breaks

Comment: Tried this `"(?s)pelicula/([0-9]*)'>(.*?)</a>"` using both advice. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is over several lines (ie it contains newline characters) you'll need to turn on "dot matches newline".

There are two way to do this:

Use the "dot matches newline" regex switch `(?s)` in your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)pelicula/([0-9]*)'>([\\w\\s]*)</a>");
```

or use the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag in the call to [`Pattern.compile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("pelicula/([0-9]*)'>([\\w\\s]*)</a>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: The input has several lines, is the source code of a page. Even using what you told me, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm searching regular expressions line by line. As I said in the original post, I search for other stuff and they are successful, but this one not, and the code is almost the same except for the pattern. I even checked if that pattern works and it does (not in java, but in a regular expression checker).