# Is this possible with one regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
{! texthere }
```

I want to capture either everything after {! until either the end or you reach the first }. So if I had

> {!text here} {!text here again} {!more text here. Oh boy!

I would want ["{!text here}", "{!text here again}", "{!more text here. oh boy!"]

I thought this would work

> {!.*}??

but the above string would come out to be ["{!text here} {!text here again} {!more text here. Oh boy!"]

I'm still very inexperienced with regexes so I don't understand why this doesn't work. I would think it would match '{!' followed by any number of characters until you get to a bracket (non greedy) which may not be there.

Comment: The easiest way to adapt this is to use non-greedy Kleene star, usually represented as `.*?`. Are you using a regular expression language that has that available? Not all do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
({![^}]+}?)
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/c56nIGOC4Wz56dsx)

Then recover the capture group `$1` which corresponds to the first set of parenthesis.

Using this way, you have to use a "match all" type of function because the regex itself is made to match a single group function

This way doesn't use any look around. Also the use of `^}` should limit the number of regex engine cycle since it is searching for the next `}` as a breaker instead of having to do the whole expression then backtrack.

Comment: @user1652427 didn't you want to capture everything after `{!`?

Comment: From the question he wants the delimiters also : `I would want ["{!text here}", "{!text here again}", "{!more text here. oh boy!"]`

Answer (score 5):

Using [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<={!)[^}]+`:

```
In [8]: import re

In [9]: str="{!text here} {!text here again} {!more text here. Oh boy!"

In [10]: re.findall('(?<={!)[^}]+',str)
Out[10]: ['text here', 'text here again', 'more text here. Oh boy!']
```

That is positive lookbehind where by any non `}` character is matched if following `{!`.

Comment: Ahh amazing! I tried doing a negative lookahead at some point, but I guess I need to read over lookarounds and actually understand them. This is what I needed. I'll mark it as an answer as soon as I'm allowed to!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use a reluctant quantifier:

```
{!.*?}?
```

This will cause the `.` to stop matching as soon as the first following `}` is found, instead of the last.

I had a question about greedy and reluctant quantifiers that has a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/when-it-comes-to-regex-what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant).

Another option would be to specify the characters that are allowed to come between the two curly braces like so:

```
{![^}]*}?
```

This specifies that there cannot be a closing curly brace matched within your pattern.

Comment: @Nolonar, not sure actually. I just copied the regex they were using and added the reluctant modifier to the `*`.

Comment: On the example string in my question, I'm getting just 3 matches of {!

Comment: I believe `??` is a Perl construct which means "Match 0 or 1 time, not greedily".

Comment: `??` has a special meaning and I can't remember what it is

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx the `??` at the end "Matches the previous element zero or one time, but as few times as possible", though I don't understand why he'd want the match to contain `{!` yet not `}`

Comment: @jjnguy: By using `??` at the end, you will end up only matching `{!` for the first regex. The second regex works due to the greedy quantifier of `[^}]*`

Answer (score 1):

if your tool/language supports perl regex, try this:

```
(?<={!)[^}]*
```