# Regex - Match.end() is not correct

Tags: java, regex

I have a string (`input`), within the string I want to find the following patter:

```
String pattern = "(src=)(\".*\")";
```

Then my aim is to replace the content with the new value.

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

String toReplace = "TESTTEST";

if (m.find()) {

    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    int start = m.start();
    int end = m.end();  

    res = res.append(m.group(1)).append("\"").append(toReplace).append("\" ");

    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(input);

    build.replace(start, end, res.toString());
}
```

The problem is when I have for e.g. this text in the input string

```
<param src="hallo.gif" width="1024" height="768" />
```

and using the code above - I get following output:

```
<param src="TESTTEST" />
```

but it should be actually:

```
<param src="TESTTEST" width="1024" height="768" />
```

I have noticed already that `m.end()` doesn't deliver the correct value, but I have no clue why, I tried also with a dollar symbol at the end of pattern, but then `m.find()` stays false. Any idea?

Comment: because the regex is greedy... http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139171/2902116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is greedy - `".*"` matches `"hallo.gif" width="1024" height="768"` (from the first to the last `"` in the string).

Make the regex lazy, and it should work:

```
String pattern = "(src=)(\".*?\")";
```