# My regex search only prints out there last match

Tags: java, regex

I actually wrote a regex expression to search for web URLs in a text (full code below) but on running the code, console prints out only the last URL in the text. I don't know what's wrong and I actually used a *while* loop. See code below and kindly help make corrections. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main
{
    static String query = "This is a URL http://facebook.com" 
    + " and this is another, http://twitter.com "
    + "this is the last URL http://instagram.com"
    + " all these URLs should be printed after the code execution";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String pattern = "([\\w \\W]*)((http://)([\\w \\W]+)(.com))";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(query);

        while(m.find())
        {
             System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

On running the above code, only http://instagram.com gets printed to the console output

Comment: `[\\w \\W]*` eats up *a lot* of characters, in this case everything before `http://instagram.com`. What did you mean to achieve with that part?

Comment: @Biffen "[\\w \\W]*" is what I use to tell the compiler that there may be a few characters before each "http://"... What do u think, thanks in adv

Comment: What you call ‘*a few characters*’ will be treated by regex as ‘as many characters as possible’. If you don't want to capture them, just remove that part entirely.

Comment: Removing that part gets no result

Comment: And using (^(http://)) will only get a result when "http://" begins the text as in - "http://twitter.com is a site"

Comment: Er, yes. Who said anything about `^`?! Removing the first group should be absolutely fine. If it doesn't work you should post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will clear it for you but you are matching too many characters, your match should be as **restrictive** as possible because `regex` is **greedy** and is going to  try to match as much as possible.

here is my take on your code:

```
public class Main {


static String query = "This is a URL http://facebook.com"
                + " and this is another, http://twitter.com "
                + "this is the last URL http://instagram.com"
                + " all these URLs should be printed after the code execution";
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pattern = "(http:[/][/][Ww.]*[a-zA-Z]+.com)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(query);

        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
}

}
```

the above cote will match only your examples if you wish to match more you need to tweak it to your needs.

And a great way to live test patterns is http://www.regexpal.com/ you can tweet your pattern there to match exactly what you want just remember to replace the `\` with double `\\` in java for escaped caracters .

Answer (score 1):

I found another RegEx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

It looks for https, but seems to be valid in your case.

I'm getting all 3 URLs printed with this code :

```
public class Main {

static String query = "This is a URL http://facebook.com"
        + " and this is another, http://twitter.com "
        + "this is the last URL http://instagram.com"
        + " all these URLs should be printed after the code execution";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh! Jeez that regex expression looks ugly and intimidating but Yeah! It works Thanks I appreciate

Comment: Well, not a beauty, but a performing beast, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how reliable this pattern is, but it prints out all the URLs when I run your example.

```
(http://[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})
```

You will have to modify it if you encounter an url that looks like this:

```
http://www.instagram.com
```

As it will only capture URLs without the 'www'.

Comment: Haha, @Biffen, oops!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your regex quantifiers (i.e. the `*` and `+` characters) are greedy, meaning that they *match as much as possible*. You need to use [reluctant quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139171/what-is-the-difference-between-greedy-and-reluctant-regular-expression-quant). See the corrected code pattern below - just two extra characters - a `?` character after the `*` and `+` to *match as little as possible*.

```
String pattern = "([\\w \\W]*?)((http://)([\\w \\W]+?)(.com))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this regex:

```
http://(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)
```

For example, from this string:

```
http://ww1.amazon.com and http://npr.org
```

it extracts

```
"ww1.amazon.com"
"npr.org"
```

To break down how it works:

```
http://      is literal
( ... )      is the main capture group
\w+          find one or more alphanumeric characters
(?: ... )    ...followed by a non-capturing group
\.\w+        ...that contains a literal period followed by at least one alphanumeric
+            repeated one or more times
```

Hope this helps.